# How to use a type defined later for function annotations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, python-typing

The problem is like this:

```
class A():
    def foo() -> B:
        pass

class B():
    def bar() -> A:
        pass
```

This will raise a `NameError: name 'B' is not defined`.

For the sake of type checking, I'm not willing to change `-> B` to `-> "B"`. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround, which is much similar to C or C++.

Tested in Pycharm 3.

```
class A: pass
class B: pass

class A(object):

    def foo(self, b: B) -> B:

        #CAN auto complete
        b.bar()

        return B()

class B(object):

    def bar(self) -> A:

        return A()

#CAN auto complete
A().foo(B()).bar()
```

Comment: Actually, I would only pre-declare B, not both A and B. Like so: `class B: pass  # pre-define name B`, so that the reader has less to wonder about.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the first reference as a string (Python 3.5+):

```py
class A():
    def foo() -> 'B':
        pass

class B():
    def bar() -> A:
        pass
```

It's called "forward reference" and was laid out in [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533514/1275778) for more ways and detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no way to directly do it using the annotation syntax, but one can modify the `__annotations__` dictionary of a function object.

```
class A():
    def foo():
        pass

class B():
    def bar() -> A:
        pass

A.foo.__annotations__["return"] = B
```