# How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

I have the following code in Python 3:

```
class Position:

    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other: Position) -> Position:
        return Position(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

But my editor (PyCharm) says that the reference `Position` can not be resolved (in the `__add__` method). How should I specify that I expect the return type to be of type `Position`?

I think this is actually a PyCharm issue. It actually uses the information in its warnings, and code completion.

[image]

But correct me if I'm wrong, and need to use some other syntax.

Comment: The current state of typing PEPs: https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/VIZEBX5EYMSYIJNDBF6DMUMZOCWHARSO/

Answer (score 1641, accepted):

**TL;DR**: As of today (2019), in Python 3.7+ you can turn this feature on using a "future" statement, `from __future__ import annotations`.

(The behaviour enabled by `from __future__ import annotations` *might* become the default in future versions of Python, and [was going](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) to be made the default in Python 3.10. However, the change in 3.10 [was reverted](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/thread/CLVXXPQ2T2LQ5MP2Y53VVQFCXYWQJHKZ/) at the last minute, and now may not happen at all. Python 3.11 [does not include it](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-563-may-not-be-the-future))

In Python 3.6 or below, you should use a string.

---

I guess you got this exception:

```
NameError: name 'Position' is not defined
```

This is because `Position` must be defined before you can use it in an annotation, unless you are using Python with [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) changes enabled.

### Python 3.7+: `from __future__ import annotations`

Python 3.7 introduces [PEP 563: postponed evaluation of annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/). A module that uses the future statement `from __future__ import annotations` will store annotations as strings automatically:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Position:
    def __add__(self, other: Position) -> Position:
        ...
```

This had been scheduled to become the default in Python 3.10, but this change has now been postponed. Since Python still is a dynamically typed language so no type-checking is done at runtime, typing annotations should have no performance impact, right? Wrong! Before Python 3.7, the typing module used to be [one of the slowest python modules in core](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0560/#performance) so **for code that involves importing the `typing` module, you will see an [up to 7 times increase in performance](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-560-core-support-for-typing-module-and-generic-types) when you upgrade to 3.7.**

### Python <3.7: use a string

[According to PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references), you should use a string instead of the class itself:

```
class Position:
    ...
    def __add__(self, other: 'Position') -> 'Position':
       ...
```

If you use the Django framework, this may be familiar, as Django models also use strings for forward references (foreign key definitions where the foreign model is `self` or is not declared yet). This should work with Pycharm and other tools.

### Sources

The relevant parts of PEP 484 and PEP 563, to spare you the trip:

> ## [Forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)
>
> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.
>
> A situation where this occurs commonly is the definition of a container class, where the class being defined occurs in the signature of some of the methods. For example, the following code (the start of a simple binary tree implementation) does not work:
>
> ```
> class Tree:
>     def __init__(self, left: Tree, right: Tree):
>         self.left = left
>         self.right = right
> ```
>
> To address this, we write:
>
> ```
> class Tree:
>     def __init__(self, left: 'Tree', right: 'Tree'):
>         self.left = left
>         self.right = right
> ```
>
> The string literal should contain a valid Python expression (i.e., compile(lit, '', 'eval') should be a valid code object) and it should evaluate without errors once the module has been fully loaded. The local and global namespace in which it is evaluated should be the same namespaces in which default arguments to the same function would be evaluated.

and PEP 563:

> ## [Implementation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#implementation)
>
> In Python 3.10, function and variable annotations will no longer be evaluated at definition time. Instead, a string form will be preserved in the respective `__annotations__` dictionary. Static type checkers will see no difference in behavior, whereas tools using annotations at runtime will have to perform postponed evaluation.
>
> ...
>
> ### [Enabling the future behavior in Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7)
>
> The functionality described above can be enabled starting from Python 3.7 using the following special import:
>
> ```
> from __future__ import annotations
> ```

### Things that you may be tempted to do instead

#### A. Define a dummy `Position`

Before the class definition, place a dummy definition:

```
class Position(object):
    pass


class Position(object):
    ...
```

This will get rid of the `NameError` and may even look OK:

```
>>> Position.__add__.__annotations__
{'other': __main__.Position, 'return': __main__.Position}
```

But is it?

```
>>> for k, v in Position.__add__.__annotations__.items():
...     print(k, 'is Position:', v is Position)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
return is Position: False
other is Position: False
```

#### B. Monkey-patch in order to add the annotations:

You may want to try some Python metaprogramming magic and write a decorator
to monkey-patch the class definition in order to add annotations:

```
class Position:
    ...
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

The decorator should be responsible for the equivalent of this:

```
Position.__add__.__annotations__['return'] = Position
Position.__add__.__annotations__['other'] = Position
```

At least it seems right:

```
>>> for k, v in Position.__add__.__annotations__.items():
...     print(k, 'is Position:', v is Position)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
return is Position: True
other is Position: True
```

Probably too much trouble.

Comment: Right, this is less a PyCharm issue and more a Python 3.5 PEP 484 issue. I suspect you'd get the same warning if you ran it through the mypy type tool.

Comment: @JoelBerkeley I just tested it and type parameters worked for me on 3.6, just don't forget to import from `typing` as any type you use must be in scope when the string is evaluated.

Comment: ah, my mistake, i was only putting `''` round the class, not the type parameters

Comment: Important note to anyone using `from __future__ import annotations` - this must be imported before all other imports.

Comment: This answer fixes the NameError, but produces bad behaviour. The code in the question (and therefore the answer) always returns an instance of `Position`, when it should probably return an instance of the current class (which might be a subclass). See the answer from @vbraun for type annotations when implementing this correctly.

Comment: According to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#id5 the new annotation behaviour activates in Python 3.10, not Python 4.

Comment: none of those solutions works if the type is used in a decorator argument before the function declaration, i had to use a string and change the behavior of my personal overload decorator implementation.

Comment: You said that `typing` is one of the slowest core modules. Is it possible to use any `__future__` module (now, in Python 3.7+) to replace `typing`'s "subscriptable" `List, Set` etc.?

Comment: @minseong: `__future__` features aren't "modules", and they're only used to enable changes in syntax that can't be fixed by modules. You seem to have missed that `typing` is already *much* faster in 3.7, no need to do anything to get the speedup aside from "use 3.7 or higher". If you want to avoid the `typing` subscriptable types like `List` *entirely*, you'll need to go to 3.9, where [the standard types (e.g. `list`) can be subscripted for annotations (e.g. `x: list[int]`)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections) w/o importing `typing`.

Comment: The answer from @vbraun solves the problem of inheritance, but it does this be issuing a *new instance* of the current class. 

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64938978) solves the inheritance problem dynamically, returning the class of the current instance -- *not* a new instance.

Comment: Is there a way to specify that the return type of a function is the current class, whatever that may be? e.g., `@classmethod def f(cls) -> CurrentClass:` where `CurrentClass` evaluates to whatever `cls` would be at runtime? So that if `A` and `B` inherit from the class that implements `f`, then `A.f() -> A` and `B.f() -> B`?

Comment: @PauloScardine may I suggest adding a shoutout to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64938978/977046 as a more inheritance-friendly route?  I almost missed that one because it has the least votes so I feel like adding something about it to the body of your (deservedly) high-ranked answer could help people avoid a potential gotcha down the road.

Comment: From PEP673: `from typing import Self` might make this much easier in the future (seems to be PY3.11 feature)

Comment: What about using a string as a dummy definition rather than a class: `Position = 'Position'`? Would that avoid the identity problem?

Comment: The `__future__` import still needs to be used in Python 3.10 as far as I can tell.

Comment: Python 3.11 introduced the `Self` annotation. https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#whatsnew311-pep673

Comment: Thank you very, very much for this information.  Not only about what works and why, but also the fact that it was going to be part of Python 3.10, but was dropped just before the release was made.

Answer (score 207):

[PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) which is implemented in **Python 3.11**, adds the [`Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) type.

```
from typing import Self    

class Position:

    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        return type(self)(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

Returning `Self` is often a good idea, but you must return an object of the same type as `self`, which means calling `type(self)` rather than `Position`.

---

For older versions of Python (currently 3.7 and later), use the [`typing-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) package. One of its purposes is to

> Enable use of new type system features on older Python versions. For example, `typing.TypeGuard` is new in Python 3.10, but `typing_extensions` allows users on previous Python versions to use it too.

Then you just import from `typing_extensions` instead of `typing`, e.g. `from typing_extensions import Self`.

Comment: With Python 3.11, this solution become the least kludgy and most succinct.

Comment: Any chance they are back porting this to `__future__`, etc?

Comment: No. `__future__` is more about making breaking syntactic features opt-in now, then making it required in a future version. (Which is not to say that a third-party library couldn't provide it now, but it won't be part of the standard library in already existing Python versions.)

Comment: I believe it's already available as part of `typing_extensions`, but `mypy` doesn't understand it yet. The Python 3.11 tracking issue is available here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12840#issue-1244203018

Comment: @cj81499 Good point, I forgot to check that module.

Comment: **Note** this is different from using `from __future__ import annotations` and annotating with `Position`, where `__add__` on a subclass `SubPosition` accepts and returns a `Position`. With `Self`, it requires and returns a `SubPosition`. Both approaches can be correct, it depends on the specific use case

Comment: (they are of course the same if the class is marked `@final`)

Comment: `Self` from `typing_extensions` raises the following error when running mypy on the code:
`error: Variable "typing_extensions.Self" is not valid as a type` and
`note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases`

Comment: As presented, the use of `Self` as type hint is misleading, since `__add__()` will always return an instance of `Position`. `Self` would be the correct type hint, if in the body of `__add__()` you'd replace `Position` with `type(self)`, so that the method returns an instance of the respective subclass. As the code stands now, `Self` should not be used, but `Position` with `__future__.annotations` or `'Position'` respectively.

Comment: Ah, good point. Now I'm trying to decide if there are any significant drawbacks to using `type(self)` in place of `Position` in the definition. Probably not?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I just upgraded to Python 3.11 so I could use `Self` instead of the kludgy `TypeVar` approach.

Comment: @cj81499 PEP 673 (Self type) entry in the `mypy` [https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12840#issue-1244203018](issue) you pointed out is now marked as checked.

Answer (score 58):

As of Python 3.11 (released in late 2022), there is  available `typing.Self` designed for this purpose. Check [PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/)!

For previous Python versions, one had to consider that the name 'Position' is not available at the time the class body itself is parsed. I don't know how you are using the type declarations, but Python's PEP 484 - which is what most mode should use if using these typing hints say that you can simply put the name as a string at this point:

```
def __add__(self, other: 'Position') -> 'Position':
    return Position(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

Check the PEP 484 [section on forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) - tools conforming to that will know to unwrap the class name from there and make use of it. (It is always important to have in mind that the Python language itself does nothing with these annotations. They are usually meant for static-code analysis, or one could have a library/framework for type-checking at runtime - but you have to explicitly set that.)

**Update**: Also, as of Python 3.7, check out [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/). As of Python 3.8, it is possible to write `from __future__ import annotations` to defer the evaluation of annotations. Forward-referencing classes should work straightforward.

**Update 2**: As of Python 3.10, PEP 563 is being retought, and it may be that [PEP 649](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0649/) is used in instead - it would simply allow the class name to be used, plain, without any quotes: the pep proposal is that it is resolved in a lazy way.

**Update 3**: As of Python 3.11, PEPs 563 and 649 to resolve forward references, mentioned above are still contending and it is likely none of them will go forward as it is now.

Answer (score 45):

Specifying the type as string is fine, but always grates me a bit that we are basically circumventing the parser. So you better not misspell any one of these literal strings:

```
def __add__(self, other: 'Position') -> 'Position':
    return Position(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

A slight variation is to use a bound typevar, at least then you have to write the string only once when declaring the typevar:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='Position')

class Position:

    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other: T) -> T:
        return Position(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

Comment: I wish Python had a `typing.Self` to specify this explicitly.

Comment: I came here looking to see if something like your `typing.Self` existed.  Returning a hard coded string fails to return the correct type when leveraging polymorphism.

In my case I wanted to implement a **deserialize** classmethod.  I settled on returning a dict (kwargs) and calling `some_class(**some_class.deserialize(raw_data))`.

Comment: The type annotations used here are appropriate when implementing this correctly to use subclasses. However, the implementation returns `Position`, and not the class, so the example above is technically incorrect. The implementation should replace `Position(` with something like `self.__class__(`.

Comment: Additionally, the annotations say that the return type depends on `other`, but most probably it actually depends on `self`. So, you would need to put the annotation on `self` to describe the correct behaviour (and maybe `other` should just be `Position` to show that it's not tied to the return type).

This can also be used for cases when you are only working with `self`. e.g. `def __aenter__(self: T) -> T:`

Comment: The current implementation does not return a `T` (subclass of Position), but a `Position` (base class). So the type hint `-> T` is incorrect. You can of course `return type(self)(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)`

Comment: @ScottP., @AlexanderHuszagh: There is no need for a `typing.Self`. Use e.g. `def __add__(self: T, other: Position) -> T`. You comments prompted me to write an answer.

Comment: Not only is this answer's `T` suggestion incorrect, the proposed fixes in the comments are incorrect too - they return an object of `self`'s type, but the annotation says to return `other`'s type. There are ways around that, but this fundamentally doesn't seem like a case where the code should even try for that kind of implicit return type adjustment. Just use `'Position'`.

Comment: If you really hate writing out the type name that much, you'll be able to write `T: TypeAlias = 'Position'` and then use `T` as an annotation [some time soon](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0613/). `TypeAlias` recently got added to `typing_extensions`, and it should be in `typing` eventually.

Comment: `typing.Self` will be available in Python 3.11 (according to [PEP-673](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/)).

Answer (score 31):

If you only care about fixing the `NameError: name 'Position' is not defined`, you can either specify the class name as a string:

```
def __add__(self, other: 'Position') -> 'Position':
```

Or if you use Python 3.7 or higher, add the following line to the top of your code (just before the other imports)

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

However, if you also want this to work for subclasses, and return the specific subclass, you need to annotate the method as being a [generic method](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-functions), by using a `TypeVar`.

What is slightly uncommon is that the `TypeVar` is bound to the type of `self`. Basically, this typing hinting tells the type checker that the return type of `__add__()` and `copy()` are the same type as `self`.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Position)

class Position:
    
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __add__(self: T, other: Position) -> T:
        return type(self)(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
    
    def copy(self: T) -> T:
        return type(self)(self.x, self.y)
```

Comment: @Arjan. you are right. I'm so accustomed to `from __future__ import annotations` that I probably forgot. Thanks for pointing this out. I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: what is the letter  ' T ' ?

Comment: @Eildosa: "T" is defined as a TypeVar. Think of it as "any type". In the defintion `copy(self: T) -> T` this means that whatever object you throw at `copy()`, `copy()` will always return an object of the same type. In this case, T is a TypeVar "bound" to Postion, which means "any type that is either `Position`, or a subclass of `Position`". Search for TypeVar to learn more about it.

Comment: Are there any clever tricks to have a generic `Self` that can be reused?

Comment: How does that look for a @classmethod?

Comment: Isn't `T = TypeVar('T', bound=Position)` referencing `Position` before it is defined?

Answer (score 18):

When a string-based type hint is acceptable, the `__qualname__` item can also be used. It holds the name of the class, and it is available in the body of the class definition.

```
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def make_new(cls) -> __qualname__:
        return cls()
```

By doing this, renaming the class does not imply modifying the type hints. But I personally would not expect smart code editors to handle this form well.

Comment: This is especially useful because it does not hardcode the class name, so it keeps working in subclasses.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will work with the postponed evaluation of annotations (PEP 563), so I've [asked a question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59375599/857390).

Comment: Note that this is not a valid annotation as far as `mypy` is concerned.

Comment: [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64938978) fixes the hardcoding in a different manner

Comment: @user2426679 both this answer and the one you are referencing are not valid type annotations. Use the bound typevar approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63237226/5014455

Comment: This works well in IntelliJ IDE

Answer (score 8):

edit: @juanpa.arrivillaga brought to my attention a better way to do this; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63237226

It's recommended to do the above answer instead of this one below.

[*old answer below, kept for posterity*]

I ❤️ [Paulo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533514)

However, there's a point to be made about type hint inheritance in relation to self, which is that if you type hint by using a literal copy paste of the class name as a string, then your type hint won't inherit in a correct or consistent way.

The solution to this is to provide return type hint by putting the type hint on the return in the function itself.

✅ For example, do this:

```
class DynamicParent:
  def func(self):
    # roundabout way of returning self in order to have inherited type hints of the return
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/64938978
    _self:self.__class__ = self
    return _self
```

❌ *Instead* of doing this:

```
class StaticParent:
  def func(self) -> 'StaticParent':
    return self
```

Below is the reason why you want to do the type hint via the roundabout ✅ way shown above

```
class StaticChild(StaticParent):
  pass

class DynamicChild(DynamicParent):
  pass

static_child = StaticChild()
dynamic_child = DynamicChild()
```

✅ `dynamic_child` screenshot shows that type hinting works correctly when referencing the self:

[image]

❌ `static_child` screenshot shows that type hinting is mistakenly pointing at the parent class, i.e. the type hint does not change correctly with inheritance; it is `static` because it will always point at the parent even when it should point at the child

[image]

Comment: this is not a valid type annotation, and not the correct way to type annotate what you are trying to express, which should be annotated with a type variable bound to the parent class

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you post an answer to this question that is `annotated with a type variable bound to the parent class`?  It's unclear to me how one would bind a type variable to the parent class that refers to the subsequent children instances.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63237226/5014455

Comment: Nice! It works with VSCode Intellisense. I am wondering if this assignment `_self:self.__class__ = self` would introduce any overhead (?)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 11):
    from typing import Self
else:
    from typing_extensions import Self


class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name: str, says: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.says = says

    @classmethod
    def from_description(cls, description: str = "|") -> Self:
        descr = description.split("|")
        return cls(descr[0], descr[1])
```

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a generic page.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75691560/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.11+ there is a 'Self' type hint in the 'typings' module.

For Cython/mypyc users who might have stumbled into this like me; it doesn't matter.. The compiler is smart enough to infer that the type specified in the function parameter correspond to the enclosing class type