# Python parameter annotations unresolved reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

Why does it say that it can not find my class? Why should I create another class with the same name in order to make make it not complain?

```
from typing import Dict


class WeekDay:

    def __init__(self, day_number, day_name):
        self.day_name = day_name
        self.day_number = day_number

    @staticmethod
    def get_week_days() -> Dict[str, WeekDay]:  # WeekDay unresolved reference error
        weekdays = {
            "monday": WeekDay(1, "Monday"),
            "tuesday": WeekDay(2, "Tuesday"),
            "wednesday": WeekDay(3, "Wednesday"),
            "thursday": WeekDay(4, "Thursday"),
            "friday": WeekDay(5, "Friday"),
            "saturday": WeekDay(6, "Saturday"),
            "sunday": WeekDay(7, "Sunday")
        }
        return weekdays
```

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I specify that the return type of a method is the same as the class itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From docs ([Section Forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references))

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.
>
> A situation where this occurs commonly is the definition of a
>   container class, where the class being defined occurs in the signature
>   of some of the methods.

so in order to solve that just wrap the type with quotes, like this:

```
from typing import Dict


class WeekDay:
    def __init__(self, day_number, day_name):
        self.day_name = day_name
        self.day_number = day_number

    @staticmethod
    def get_week_days() -> Dict[str, 'WeekDay']:  # quote WeekDay 
        weekdays = {
            "monday": WeekDay(1, "Monday"),
            "tuesday": WeekDay(2, "Tuesday"),
            "wednesday": WeekDay(3, "Wednesday"),
            "thursday": WeekDay(4, "Thursday"),
            "friday": WeekDay(5, "Friday"),
            "saturday": WeekDay(6, "Saturday"),
            "sunday": WeekDay(7, "Sunday")
        }

        return weekdays
```

Answer (score 15):

From Python3.7, you can use:
`from __future__ import annotations`

Comment: and what does that do?

Comment: In the example you can then work with WeekDay class without import issues.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot reference a class from its own definition

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        pass

    bar = A.foo
```

this will raise the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    class A:
  File "/home/shmulik/so/ans.py", line 28, in A
    bar = A.foo
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

as a workaround this issue, [PEP484 - Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) (thanks to @ashwini-chaudhary for the comment) allows to write the class definition as a string.

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that
>   definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

so we can for example write:

```
class A:
    def foo(self, x: 'A'):
        pass
```

and this class will be interpreted happily by python.

## Side Note

so hey you mentioned on the first example that we cannot reference class from its definition, so why this code works?

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        A.bar()

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        print(42)


A().foo()
```

this code works as the python interpreter skips the body of the method definition of `foo()` during the definition of class `A`, and only on the last line, when `foo()` is called (and class A is defined), the python interpreter executes the body of `foo()` and calling `A.bar()`.