# How to annotate that a classmethod returns an instance of that class

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Using [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), is there a way to annotate that a classmethod returns an instance of that class?

e.g.

```
@dataclass
class Bar:

    foo: str

    @classmethod
    def new_from_foo(cls, foo) -> Bar
        ...
```

or

```
    @classmethod
    def new_from_foo(cls, foo) -> cls
```

Comment: Doesn't it work? It should work in Python3.7: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-563-postponed-evaluation-of-annotations

Comment: @Sraw  I was trying with 3.6. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: But there isn't `dataclass` in Python3.6...

Comment: I'm using the backport. https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/

Comment: Don't use `Bar` as the return annotation. A proper classmethod should also support subclassing. You don't want `BarSubclass.new_from_foo()` to return a `Bar` instance, do you?

Comment: @Aran-Fey agreed. Just not sure how to achieve the that.

Comment: See down v there v?

Comment: Yip - was just saying I agreed. Trying out your solution atm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify that the return type of a method is the same as the class itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is to use a [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) to connect the `cls` parameter to the return annotation:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')

class Bar:
    @classmethod
    def new_from_foo(cls: Type[T], foo) -> T:
        ...
```

Comment: This works, but somehow dose not work with dataclasses. I will investigate to try understand why.

Comment: @GaryvanderMerwe Huh, you're right. I didn't realize. I'll investigate that.

Comment: Looks like a bug in mypy to me, honestly. As far as I can tell, it only happens in classmethods - and only in dataclasses. Edit: Found the relevant [github issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5263).