# Python type hinting own class in method

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Edit**: I notice people commenting about how the type hint should not be used with `__eq__`, and granted, it shouldn't. But that's not the point of my question. My question is **why** can't the class be used as type hint in the method **parameters**, but can be used in the method **itself**?

---

Python type hinting has proven very useful for me when working with PyCharm. However, I've come across behaviour I find strange, when trying to use a class' own type in its methods.

For example:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        pass

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id
```

Here, when typing `other.`, the property `id` is not offered automatically. I was hoping to solve it by defining `__eq__` as follows:

```
    def __eq__(self, other: Foo):
        return self.id == other.id
```

However, this gives `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined`. But when I use the type within the method, `id` is offered after writing `other.`:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        other: Foo
        return self.id == other.id
```

My question is, why is it not possible to use the class' own type for type hinting the parameters, while it is possible within the method?

Comment: That's the wrong type hint for `__eq__` anyway. `__eq__` is supposed to take arbitrary other objects and return `NotImplemented` for types it can't compare.

Comment: While I agree with you, this is just a simple example to show. For any method of class ```Foo```, it's not possible to use ```Foo``` as type hint.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The name `Foo` doesn't yet exist, so you need to use `'Foo'` instead. (`mypy` and other type checkers should recognize this as a forward reference.)

```
def __eq__(self, other: 'Foo'):
    return self.id == other.id
```

Alternately, you can use

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

which prevents evaluation of *all* annotations and simply stores them as strings for later reference. (This will be the default in Python 3.10.)

Finally, as also pointed out in the comments, `__eq__` should *not* be hinted this way in the first place. The second argument should be an arbitrary object; you'll return `NotImplemented` if you don't know how to compare your instance to it. (Who knows, maybe *it* knows how to compare itself to *your* instance. If `Foo.__eq__(Foo(), Bar())` returns `NotImplemented`, then Python will try `Bar.__eq__(Bar(), Foo())`.)

```
from typing import Any


def __eq__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
    if isinstance(other, Foo):
        return self.id == other.id
    return NotImplemented
```

or using duck-typing,

```
def __eq__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
    # Compare to anything with an `id` attribute
    try:
        return self.id == other.id
    except AttributeError:
        return NotImplemented
```

In either case, the `Any` hint is optional.

Comment: "The name Foo doesn't yet exist, so you need to use 'Foo' instead". This is an answer in the direction I'm looking for. You say it does not exist yet, but it can be used in the method itself. My question is why does Python think Foo does not yet exists, as the method is per definition inside the Foo class?

Comment: @R.dV as far as I understand it, Python only evaluates the contents of a function/method once it is called. The function definition on the other hand needs to be evaluated before actually calling it. So you define a class, but before the class is defined its methods must be known, so the definitions need to be evaluated, but in one method definition you tell Python, that it takes a class that is not yet defined, so it throws up on you. Not sure if that's 100% correct, but I hope that could clear things up

Answer (score 18):

As of python 3.11 it's now possible to use `Self` to type hint the current class.

For example, this is now valid python:

```
from typing import Self

class Foo:
   def return_self(self) -> Self:
      ...
      return self
```

Here is a link to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self)

And is a link to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695453/python-type-hints-self-referential-type-checking) on stack overflow