# Python: Unknown type hint does not raise exception with __future__ import

Tags: python, type-hinting

All classes need to be defined before they can be used as a type hint. To get around it in some scenarios, the `__future__` import [is recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel). That's why the following code works fine (in Python 3.7):

```
from __future__ import annotations


class Person:
    def get_relative(name: str) -> Person:
        ...
```

Without the `__future__` import it would raise a `NameError`. But this code works fine too:

```
from __future__ import annotations


class Person:
    def get_relative(name: BlahBlahTypoWhatever) -> Person:
        ...
```

I expected something like `NameError: name 'BlahBlahTypoWhatever' is not defined`. Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python itself does no type checking whatsoever, so it won't raise any error about wrong types.

The `annotations` future is simply implicitly changing all annotations to strings, i.e. this is equivalent:

```
from __future__ import annotations

def foo(bar: Baz): pass
```

```
def foo(bar: 'Baz'): pass
```

Since your annotation is a string now, and Python doesn't do anything with it, there's absolutely no resolution of that name going on at any point, so it doesn't raise any errors.