# Type-annotating a method with the surrounding class in python

Tags: python-3.x

When I annotate a method argument with the enclosing class as its type in python, I get an error that the type is not (yet) defined. E.g. the code

```
class Foobar:
    def foo(self, bar: Foobar):
        ...
```

produces `NameError: name 'Foobar' is not defined`. What's the correct approach to this?

Comment: This might provide some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a future import:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Foobar:
    def foo(self, bar: Foobar):
        ...
```