# Can mypy select a method return type based on the type of the current object?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

In the following code, calling the `clone()` method on an instance of A will return an instance of type A, calling it on an instance of B will return an instance of type B, and so on. The purpose is to create a new instance which is identical to the current one but has a different internally generated primary key, so it can be edited from there and safely saved as a new item.

`???` is some kind of type qualifier, but I'm not sure what the right choice is.

```
class A:
    def clone(self) -> ???:
        cls = self.__class__
        result = cls.__new__(cls)
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            setattr(result, k, deepcopy(v))
        result.id = self.__generate_id()
        return result

class B(A):
   def do_b(self):
       pass
```

I currently replaced `???` with `'A'`. This works, but if I want to clone an object of type B, I have to cast the return value if I want to call B-specific methods on it:

```
b = B().clone()
b.do_b()  # type error!

b = cast(B, B().clone())
b.do_b()  # OK
```

However, it's guaranteed that calling `.clone()` on an object of type B will return another object of type B, and this smacks rather too much of Java for my taste. Is there some generic-based way I can tell mypy that the method returns an object of type `__class__`, whatever that class is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using [generic methods with a generic self](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self) -- basically, annotate your `self` variable as being generic:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='A')

class A:
    def __generate_id(self) -> int:
        return 0

    def clone(self: T) -> T: 
        cls = self.__class__
        result = cls.__new__(cls)
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            setattr(result, k, deepcopy(v))
        result.id = self.__generate_id()
        return result

class B(A):
    def do_b(self):
        pass

reveal_type(A().clone())  # Revealed type is A
reveal_type(B().clone())  # Revealed type is B
```

Basically, when we call `clone()`, the `T` typevar will be bound to the type of the current instance when mypy tries type-checking the call to clone. This ends up making the return type match the type of the instance, whatever it is.

You may be wondering why I set the upper bound of `T` to `A`. This is because of the line `self.__generate_id()`. Basically, in order for that line to type-check, `self` can't be literally any type: it needs to be `A` or some subclass of `A`. The bound encodes this requirement.

Comment: What if we have a static method which returns an object of type `A`? (no possible reference to `self` since its not in the function's signature)

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533514/1720199) if someone else is looking for a broader answer.