# Workaround for TypeVar bound on a TypeVar?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, type-bounds

Is there some way of expressing this Scala code with Python's type hints?

```scala
trait List[A] {
  def ::[B >: A](x: B): List[B]
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this sort of thing

```py
class X: pass
class Y(X): pass
class Z(X): pass

xs = MyList(X(), X())  # inferred as MyList[X]
ys = MyList(Y(), Y())  # inferred as MyList[Y]

_ = xs.extended_by(X())  # inferred as MyList[X]
_ = xs.extended_by(Y())  # inferred as MyList[X]

_ = ys.extended_by(X())  # inferred as MyList[X]
_ = ys.extended_by(Y())  # inferred as MyList[Y]
_ = ys.extended_by(Z())  # inferred as MyList[X]
```

Note that the type `MyList` is initialised with, and the type it's `extended_by`, can be anything. `MyList` is immutable. See the comments for more detail.

**What I tried**

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

B = TypeVar('B')
A = TypeVar('A', bound=B)


class MyList(Generic[A]):
    def __init__(*o: A):
        ...

    def extended_by(self, x: B) -> MyList[B]:
        ...
```

but I get (where the above is in main.py)

> main.py:5: error: Type variable "main.B" is unbound
> main.py:5: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[B]" or "Protocol[B]" base class to bind "B" inside a class)
> main.py:5: note: (Hint: Use "B" in function signature to bind "B" inside a function)

Afaict, it's not allowed to bound on a `TypeVar`. Is there a workaround in this scenario?

Comment: Could you describe what you want without using Scala Code please? It is hard to find an answer without knowing Scala

Comment: I Don't really get what you want. But maybe it is to complicated. It is not really a good practise to try to apply Code Patterns from another language. I think typehints should only be minimalistic and easy to understand. Try to rethink your Problem and try to find a way that is more pythotic

Comment: I'm also not too sure about the question because of my basic knowledge of `typing`, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel), you could maybe try putting `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of the file if you are running Python 3.7+.

Comment: @joelb So to clarify, `MyList` should be initialized with some type, say `A`, and then its method `extended_by` must be invoked with an ancestor of `A` (i.e. up the MRO; it cannot be `A` itself)?

Comment: @a_guest `A` and the type you extend it by (call it `C`) can be anything. The Scala signature is clever because any two types will always have a common ancestor, here `B`. If `C` is a subclass of `A`, then `B` _is_ `A` and it becomes trivial. If `C` is a superclass of `A` then `B` is `C`. The really clever bit is when `C` is neither a superclass or subclass. Then `B` becomes the common ancestor. You've extended it by `C`, but Scala treats it as an instance of its superclass `B` instead.

Comment: @a_guest so in answer to your question, they can be any types

Comment: The code works fine for me (Python 3.6), at least in REPL. Am I missing something?

Comment: @szatkus it's a static type checking thing. runtime's largely irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to specify that `B` is a supertype of `A`. But instead of specifying that `B` should be a supertype of `A`, it is much easier to state that `B` is any type, and then the Union `A|B` is the supertype of `A` you need.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
A = TypeVar("A", covariant=True)
B = TypeVar("B")

class MyList(Generic[A]):
    def __init__(*objects: A) -> None: ...
    def extended_by(self, other: B) -> MyList[A | B]: ...

class X: pass
class Y(X): pass
class Z(X): pass


xs = MyList(X(), X())  # inferred as MyList[X]
ys = MyList(Y(), Y())  # inferred as MyList[Y]

reveal_type(xs.extended_by(X())) # inferred as MyList[X]
reveal_type(xs.extended_by(Y())) # inferred as MyList[X]

reveal_type(ys.extended_by(X()))  # inferred as MyList[X]
reveal_type(ys.extended_by(Y()))  # inferred as MyList[Y]
reveal_type(ys.extended_by(Z()))  # inferred as MyList[Y|Z]
# MyList[Y|Z] is a subtype of MyList[X]
```

If `MyList` is immutable, its type variable is most likely covariant. That means that
`MyList[X]` is a subclass of `MyList[Y]`. I took the liberty to make your generic parameter covariant, which will also make implementing the `extended_by` method easier.

Note: If you have to use Python<3.10, make sure to replace `|` with `Union`.

Note 2: This is the same approach as, for example `list.__add__`, see
the code in [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/c7431181b3f062f310bedb361d77c3a2351aaefb/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L998).

Answer (score -2):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import (
    TYPE_CHECKING,
    Generic,
    TypeVar,
)

B = TypeVar('B')
A = TypeVar('A')


class MyList(Generic[A]):
    def __init__(*o: A):
        ...

    def extended_by(self, x: B) -> MyList[B]:
        ...


class Y:
    ...


class X:
    ...


ys = MyList(Y(), Y())
xs = ys.extended_by(X())
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_locals()
```

This produces :

```
test.py:32: note: Revealed local types are:
test.py:32: note:     xs: test.MyList[test.X*]
test.py:32: note:     ys: test.MyList[test.Y*]
```

I didn’t understand the link between `A` and `B`. Could you give an example with for instance class `Y` and `X` so I can update my answer?

Comment: thanks but you're missing the bounds, which are central to the question. Specifically, with `Y` and `X` as you've defined them, `xs` should be inferred as `MyList[object]`

Comment: see the comments under the question for an explanation of `A` and `B`

Comment: i do see why you've come to this solution from the section where I've said "I'm trying to achieve this sort of thing". That's one example of what such a bound does, but it's missing some other crucial functionality of the scala trait

Comment: i've added an example to the question

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the method `extended_by` should cast the result to the most common ancestor between its argument and the generic A? I don’t know 1. how to do that in python, 2. the use case.

Comment: If you want something that act the same way in that list, why not cast to the root ancestor? Or you can use a `Protocol`.

Comment: it won't be a cast, per se, but yes its the common ancestor. The use cases are numerous, though i can't remember why i wanted this. In scala, this is one way to construct lists. Casting might make the implementation type check but i'm interested in the API. I don't see how a protocol would help