# How to tell to mypy, that type of one argument should be subclass of type of another?

Tags: python, mypy

I'd like to specify, that for function `f(a,b)` the type of argument `b` should be subclass of argument `a`. I.g.

```
from typing import TypeVar
class A:...
class B(A):...
class C(): ...

def f(a, b):...

f(A(), B()) # ok
f(B(), A()) # not ok
f(A(), C()) # not ok
```

From 1st view it seems single typevar solves the problem:

```
T= TypeVar('T')
def f(a:T, b:T):...
```

But in this case the SECOND argument is always should be subclass of FIRST, which is not flexible obviously. Is there a way to specify types relation explicitly? I was trying to make one typevar bound to another but it's not working.

```
T= TypeVar('T')
T2= TypeVar('T2', bound=T) # Constraints cannot be parametrized by type variables
```

Comment: [related/duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57590086/5986907)