# Changing type argument of Python with subclassing

Tags: python, generics, subclass, mypy, typing

Python's typing system allows for generics in classes:

```py
class A(Generic[T]):
    def get_next(self) -> T
```

which is very handy.  However, even in 3.11 with the Self type, I cannot find a way to change the type argument (the `T`) without specifying the class name.  Here's the recommended usage from PEP 673: Self Type: https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/a

```py
class Container(Generic[T]):
    def foo(
        self: Container[T],
    ) -> Container[str]:
        # maybe implementing something like:
        return self.__class__([str(x) for x in self])
```

The problem is if I want to subclass container:

```py
class SuperContainer(Container[T]):
    def time_travel(self): ...
```

And then if I have an instance of SuperContainer and call foo on it, the typing will be wrong, and think that it's a Container not SuperContainer.

```py
sc = SuperContainer([1, 2, 3])
sc2 = sc.foo()
reveal_type(sc2)  # mypy: Container[str]
sc2.time_travel()  # typing error: only SuperContainers can time-travel
isinstance(sc2, SuperContainer)  # True
```

Is there an accepted way to allow a program to change the type argument in the superclass that preserves the typing of the subclass?

Comment: as a guess I'd say no. python doesn't support generics that depend on other generics. This may well be an example of the limitations raised in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57590086/5986907) or [this mypy issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548#issuecomment-1079724618)

Comment: Alternative solution for this problem was proposed by @sobolevn in [`dry-python/returns`](https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/hkt.html) library. The link above points to explanation of higher-kind types (exactly feature described in your question, if you remember that `self` can be annotated as well). This solution involves `mypy` plugin to do the necessary magic.

Comment: Thank you. If you write it up as an answer I’ll give a secondary (or primary) bounty

Answer (score 5):

To solve this, you need a second generic type argument, to represent the return type of `foo`.

```py
SelfStr = TypeVar("SelfStr", bound="Container[str, Any]", covariant=True)
```

The `Any` is okay. We'll see that later.

So far so good. Let's define the `Container`:

```py
class Container(Generic[T, SelfStr]):
    def __init__(self, contents: list[T]):
        self._contents = contents

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._contents)

    def foo(self) -> SelfStr:
        reveal_type(type(self))
        # Mypy is wrong here: it thinks that type(self) is already annotated, but in fact the type parameters are erased.
        return type(self)([str(x) for x in self])  # type: ignore

    def __repr__(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + "(" + repr(self._contents) + ")"
```

Note that we had to ignore the types in `foo`. This is because mypy has inferred the type of `type(self)` incorrectly. It thinks that `type(self)` returns `Container[...]` (or a subclass), but in fact it returns `Container` (or a subclass). You'll see that when we get to running this code.

Next, we need some way of creating a container. We want the type to look like `Container[T, Container[str, Container[str, ...]]]`.

In the first line of the class declaration, we made the second type-parameter of the class be a `SelfStr`, which is itself `Container[str, Any]`. This means that definition of `SelfStr` should become bounded to `Container[str, SelfStr]`, so we should get an upper bound of `Container[str, Container[str, ...]]` as we wanted. This works: it will only allow our recursive type (or subclasses) **or `Any`**. Unfortunately, mypy won't do inference on recursive generic types, reporting `test.Container[builtins.int, <nothing>]`, so we have to do the heavy lifting. Time for some [✨ magic ✨](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731).

```py
_ContainerStr: TypeAlias = Container[str, "_ContainerStr"]
ContainerComplete: TypeAlias = Container[T, _ContainerStr]
```

The `_ContainerStr` alias will give us the recursive part of the signature. We then expose `ContainerComplete`, which we can use as a constructor, for example:

```py
ContainerComplete[int]([1,2,3])
```

Awesome! But what about subclasses? We just have to do the same thing again, for our subclass:

```py
class SuperContainer(Container[T, SelfStr]):
    def time_travel(self):
        return "magic"
_SuperContainerStr: TypeAlias = SuperContainer[str, "_SuperContainerStr"]
SuperContainerComplete: TypeAlias = SuperContainer[T, _SuperContainerStr]
```

All done! Now let's demonstrate:

```py
sc = SuperContainerComplete[int]([3, 4, 5])
reveal_type(sc)

sc2 = sc.foo()
reveal_type(sc2)

print(sc2.time_travel())
```

Putting everything together, we get:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any, TypeAlias, TYPE_CHECKING

if not TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type = print

T = TypeVar('T')
SelfStr = TypeVar("SelfStr", bound="Container[str, Any]", covariant=True)

class Container(Generic[T, SelfStr]):
    def __init__(self, contents: list[T]):
        self._contents = contents

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._contents)

    def foo(self) -> SelfStr:
        reveal_type(type(self))
        # Mypy is wrong here: it thinks that type(self) is already annotated, but in fact the type parameters are erased.
        return type(self)([str(x) for x in self])  # type: ignore

    def __repr__(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + "(" + repr(self._contents) + ")"
_ContainerStr: TypeAlias = Container[str, "_ContainerStr"]
ContainerComplete: TypeAlias = Container[T, _ContainerStr]

class SuperContainer(Container[T, SelfStr]):
    def time_travel(self):
        return "magic"
_SuperContainerStr: TypeAlias = SuperContainer[str, "_SuperContainerStr"]
SuperContainerComplete: TypeAlias = SuperContainer[T, _SuperContainerStr]

sc = SuperContainerComplete[int]([3, 4, 5])
reveal_type(sc)

sc2 = sc.foo()
reveal_type(sc2)

print(sc2.time_travel())
```

And the output looks like this (you need a recent version of mypy):

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py:17: note: Revealed type is "Type[test.Container[T`1, SelfStr`2]]"
test.py:33: note: Revealed type is "test.SuperContainer[builtins.int, test.SuperContainer[builtins.str, ...]]"
test.py:36: note: Revealed type is "test.SuperContainer[builtins.str, test.SuperContainer[builtins.str, ...]]"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
$ python test.py
<__main__.SuperContainer object at 0x7f30165582d0>
<class '__main__.SuperContainer'>
<__main__.SuperContainer object at 0x7f3016558390>
magic
$
```

You can remove a lot of the boilerplate using metaclasses. This has the added advantage that it's inherited. If you override `__call__`, you can even get `isinstance` working properly (it doesn't work with the generic type aliases *`Complete`, it still works fine for the classes themselves).

Note that this only partially works in PyCharm:
[image: it does not report warnings on SuperContainer.foo().foo().time_travel()]

Comment: Wow -- this looks amazing.  Testing it out.  (btw +1 also for `if not TYPE_CHECKING: reveal_type = print` somehow never thought of that little usage`

Comment: (holding bounty for one more day to see if someone has a solution where the two possibilities int/str don't need to be hardcoded.  I also have cases where the type to be converted to is a Type[T] variable itself)

Comment: I don't know quite how, but I made it work with Type[T]. New answer incoming.

Comment: @MichaelScottAsatoCuthbert the bounty expires in a couple of hours :)

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue how this works, but I made it work with `Type[T]` too. I genuinely cannot explain this code so I'm just gonna copy and paste, better people than me can tell you *why*.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any, TypeAlias, TYPE_CHECKING, Type

if not TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type = print

T = TypeVar('T')
SelfStr = TypeVar("SelfStr", bound="Container[str, Any, Any]", covariant=True)
SelfTypeT = TypeVar("SelfTypeT", bound="Container[Type[Any], Any, Any]", covariant=True)

class Container(Generic[T, SelfStr, SelfTypeT]):
    def __init__(self, contents: list[T]):
        self._contents = contents

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._contents)

    def foo(self) -> SelfStr:
        reveal_type(type(self))
        # Mypy is wrong here: it thinks that type(self) is already annotated, but in fact the type parameters are erased.
        return type(self)([str(x) for x in self])  # type: ignore

    def get_types(self) -> SelfTypeT:
        return type(self)([type(x) for x in self])  # type: ignore

    def __repr__(self):
        return type(self).__name__ + "(" + repr(self._contents) + ")"
_ContainerStr: TypeAlias = Container[str, "_ContainerStr", "ContainerComplete[Type[str]]"]
_ContainerTypeT: TypeAlias = Container[Type[T], "_ContainerStr", "_ContainerTypeT[Type[type]]"]
ContainerComplete: TypeAlias = Container[T, _ContainerStr, _ContainerTypeT[T]]

class SuperContainer(Container[T, SelfStr, SelfTypeT]):
    def time_travel(self):
        return "magic"
_SuperContainerStr: TypeAlias = SuperContainer[str, "_SuperContainerStr", "SuperContainerComplete[Type[str]]"]
_SuperContainerTypeT: TypeAlias = SuperContainer[Type[T], "_SuperContainerStr", "_SuperContainerTypeT[Type[type]]"]
SuperContainerComplete: TypeAlias = SuperContainer[T, _SuperContainerStr, _SuperContainerTypeT[T]]

sc = SuperContainerComplete[int]([3, 4, 5])
reveal_type(sc)

sc2 = sc.foo()
reveal_type(sc2)

sc3 = sc.get_types()
reveal_type(sc3)

class Base:
    pass

class Impl1(Base):
    pass

class Impl2(Base):
    pass

sc4 = SuperContainerComplete[Base]([Impl1(), Impl2()])

sc5 = sc4.foo()
reveal_type(sc5)

sc6 = sc4.get_types()
reveal_type(sc6)

print(sc2.time_travel())
```

Mypy and Python are both happy with this code so I guess It Works (TM).

Comment: I think this won't work if you intentionally try to break it by directly accessing SuperContainer and instantiating it without going via SuperContainerComplete, but you can always prevent that using a metaclass.

Comment: I’ll give this a try soon.