# What is the Python / mypy equivalent of this Java generic?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I'm not sure how to express the equivalent of this Java generic by using Python's type hinting. The interface has a generic, and the method has its own generic that must extend the class's generic:

```
public interface Example<T> {
    <T_SUB extends T> T_SUB doSomething(T_SUB input);
}
```

An example implementation class, showing that the method must accept things that extend `Serializable`, and the return type is always equal to the type of the parameter.

```
public class Impl implements Example<Serializable> {
    @Override
    public <T_SUB extends Serializable> T_SUB doSomething(T_SUB input) {
        return input;
    }
}
```

And example usages:

```
Impl impl = new Impl();
StringBuilder result = impl.doSomething(new StringBuilder());
Duration result2 = impl.doSomething(Duration.ofMinutes(1));
```

I've tried various approaches in Python which will pass mypy checking, but the answer is evading me.

Comment: I don't think Python has the concept of "must extend T". But if T is an abstract base class, you can just use that. Since there can't be instances of T, anything that satisfies the type must be from a subclass.

Comment: `T` can be any type. What do you mean by "just use that"? If you mean change the return type to `Serializable` for example, then the return value is not typed correctly any more (it should be the same type as the input, not `Serializable`).

Comment: I'm saying that in place of `<T_SUB extends T>` you just use `T`.

Comment: `T doSomething(T input)`

Comment: I can do that if I have to, but it's not what I'm looking for. Feel free to add an Answer saying, "no, Python can't do that" :)

Comment: Are you possibly asking for `typing.Protocol`?

Comment: If you can get it working with `typing.Protocol` please show me how! I could not.

Comment: I don't know my way around python typing and generics to write a real answer, I'm just trying to point you in the right direction.

Comment: this might be a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590086/workaround-for-typevar-bound-on-a-typevar)