# How to specify the return type of parent method as the child class dynamically using python type hinting?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I wonder what should do if I want the IDE auto-hinting the child method? The belowing code doesn't work in Pycharm 2019.2

I can only add type hinting in the parent class but the "final type" should by determined dynamically in the child class

```py
from typing import TypeVar, List

T = TypeVar("T")


class Node:
    def __init__(self: T, neighbours: List[T]):
        self.neighbours = neighbours # The "final type" should be determined dynamically

    def get_neighbours(self) -> List[T]:
        return self.neighbours


class ChildNodeA(Node):
    def child_method_a(self):
        pass

class ChildNodeB(Node):
    def child_method_b(self):
        pass

class ChildNodeC(Node):
    def child_method_c(self):
        pass


child_node = ChildNodeA([])

for node in child_node.neighbours:
    node.child_method_a() # I want the pycharm to auto-hint child_method_a 

child_node = ChildNodeB([])
for node in child_node.neighbours:
    node.child_method_b() # I want the pycharm to auto-hint child_method_b
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your requirement correctly, but in order to have PyCharm show the `ChildNode` and `Node` methods for auto completion you just need a forward reference: `List['ChildNode']`. Note that the class is referenced via its name, i.e. as a string.

Comment: Or, in Python 3.7+ you can use `annotations` from `__future__` as nicely explained in the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel) (which might be a dupe target).

Comment: @shmee Thank you for reply. I didn't expressed my requirements well and I modified my question. The problem is I can only add type hinting in the parent class but the "final type" should by determined dynamically in the child class

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
class ChildNode(Node):
    def child_method(self) -> str:
        return 'test'
```

Comment: I didn't expressed my requirements well and I modified my question. The problem is I can only add type hinting in the parent class but the "final type" should by determined dynamically in the child class