# Can I use __qualname__ in a Python type hint with postponed annotation evaluation?

Tags: python, language-lawyer

I like using `__qualname__` for the return-type annotation of factory-style class methods, because it doesn't hardcode the classname and therefore keeps working subclasses (cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789374/857390)).

```py
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def make(cls) -> __qualname__:
        return cls()
```

Currently this seems to work fine, but I am not sure whether this will still be possible with the postponed evaluation of annotations ([PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/)): the PEP [says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#id5) that

> Annotations can only use names present in the module scope as postponed evaluation using local names is not reliable (with the sole exception of class-level names resolved by `typing.get_type_hints()`).

The PEP also [says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#id7):

> The `get_type_hints()` function automatically resolves the correct value of `globalns` for functions and classes. It also automatically provides the correct `localns` for classes.

However, the following code

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing

class Foo():
    @classmethod
    def make(cls) -> __qualname__:
        return cls()

print(typing.get_type_hints(Foo.make))
```

fails with

```
  File "qualname_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(typing.get_type_hints(Foo.make))
  File "/var/local/conda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 1004, in get_type_hints
    value = _eval_type(value, globalns, localns)
  File "/var/local/conda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 263, in _eval_type
    return t._evaluate(globalns, localns)
  File "/var/local/conda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 467, in _evaluate
    eval(self.__forward_code__, globalns, localns),
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__qualname__' is not defined
```

Commenting the `__future__` import makes the code work again, in that case it outputs

```
{'return': <class '__main__.Foo'>}
```

as expected.

**Is my use case `__qualname__` supported (which would mean that `get_type_hints` is buggy), or is this approach not possible with PEP 563?**

Comment: Your use of `__qualname__` is just incorrect. Consider `class Bar(Foo): pass`. `Bar.make()` doesn't return an instance of `Foo`; it returns an instance of `Bar`.

Comment: The correct type hint would probably be a `TypeVar`: `def make(cls: Type[T]) -> T`.

Comment: @chepner: You're correct, and I hadn't thought of this. However, with postponed evaluation that should start to work, right? Because then the annotation of `Bar.make` should be evaluated within the context of `Bar`, where `__qualname__` refers to `Bar`.

Comment: FWIW: While `mypy` does not support `__qualname__` currently, there is issue [mypy/#6473](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6473) on it. It has been accepted as describing a bug and is being worked on. I have no idea whether `get_type_hints` breaking is a bug or not – it seems to break for all class-level attributes (including types and aliases) but there is no bug report yet.

Answer (score 5):

`Foo.make` doesn't always return an instance of `Foo` (which is what `__qualname__` expands to). It returns an instance of the class it receives as an argument, which isn't necessarily `Foo`. Consider:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @classmethod
...     def make(cls):
...         return cls()
...
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     pass
...
>>> type(Bar.make())
<class '__main__.Bar'>
```

The correct type hint would be a type variable:

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound="Foo")

class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def make(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        return cls()
```

Comment: You're correct, and I hadn't thought of this. However, with postponed evaluation that should start to work, right? Because then the annotation of `Bar.make` should be evaluated within the context of `Bar`, where `__qualname__` refers to `Bar`. Assuming that `__qualname__` can still be used in annotations, that is.

Comment: With `from __future__ import annotations`, if you try to use `__qualname__` as the return type, `mypy` reports "`error: Name '__qualname__' is not defined`"

Comment: `__qualname__` only exists within the namespace of the `class` statement, not in the global scope, so (I think) by the time `mypy` tries to use it, it is out of scope.

Comment: Yes, `__qualname__` only exists in the `class` namespace. The question is whether, with postponed evaluation, this should work (in which case mypy and `get_type_hints` would be buggy).

Comment: Postponed evaluation is somewhat of a misnomer. All it means is that whatever you provide is simply stored as a string in `Foo.__annotations__`; when (or if) that string gets evaluated is entirely up to you. The matter is further complicated by the fact that `Bar.make` doesn't exist; the *lookup* resolves to `Foo.make`, and static typechecking doesn't extended to modifying the value of `__qualname__` to take into account the *runtime* type of the argument passed to `Foo.make` when you call `Bar.make()`.

Comment: `__qualname__` is simply the wrong thing to use here.

Comment: Well, there is `typing.get_type_hints` as part of the standard library, so I would expect that its implementation sets (or at least follows) the standard of how to evaluate annotations. And its documentation says that it indeed does take into account the class's namespace. The question is whether it ignores `__qualname__` on purpose or on accident.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the class namespace; it says it evaluates them using the given global and local namespaces.

Comment: From the documentation of `get_type_hints`: "It also automatically provides the correct localns for classes".

Comment: I don't see that line at https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html.

Comment: In any case, I am not interested in debugging the treatment of `__qualname__` in an annotation. I don't believe it's the right thing to use here.

Comment: Sorry, it's [in the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#id7). But you're right, this is probably not the right place to discuss this question. Thanks for your feedback!