# Is there a way to do forward declaration of classes in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, forward-declaration

I am working on a 3d rendering engine using only the standard libraries and tkinter, but I've hit a snag when trying to define a function that merges the class that it is a part of with another instance of the class.

The code

```py
class VertexCloud:

    def __init__(self, seed: Vertex = Vertex(Point(0, 0, 0), Point(0, 0, 0))):
        vertecies.append(seed)

#...

    #merge two vertex clouds
    def merge(vc: VertexCloud = VertexCloud(Vertex(Point(0, 0, 0), Point(0, 0, 0)))):
        for vertex in vc.verticies:
            verticies.append(vertex)
```

returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File"<Path>/ThreeDFamilies.py", line 126, in VertexCloud
    def merge(vc: VertexCloud = VertexCloud(Vertex(Point(0, 0, 0), Point(0, 0, 0)))):
NameError: name 'VertexCloud' is not defined
```

My only ideas of how to fix this are to either declare the class ahead of time (preferred), or define the function outside of the class. Unfortunately - although I am proficient in other languages - this is my first major project in python, so I don't have a full understanding of how this would work syntactically.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This case is documented in the [PEP 484 - Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-problem-of-forward-declarations)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify that the return type of a method is the same as the class itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel)

Comment: That's not going to be enough. The default values have the same problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any sense for `merge` to *have* a default. Also, `self` is missing in at least 3 places, and `vertices` is misspelled.

Comment: Thank you all for your submissions! I've got a lot of changes ahead of me, since this was only one of many functions with the same error that I've been putting off fixing. I'll post a solution once I have it working.