# Passing instance of class to class

Tags: python, class

I want to be able to pass an instance of `Foo` to another instance of `Foo`.

My below code doesn't work for two reasons:

1. I need to use `Foo` in `MyTypes` before `Foo` is known. I get a NameError that Foo is not known
2. In my check `isinstance(values,Foo)` my instance of `Foo` is not recognized and I get my TypeError "Type not supported".

Can someone explain me how I can fix this?

Thanks!

```
MyTypes = (list,np.ndarray, Foo)
class Foo():

    def __init__(self,values:MyTypes) -> None:
        self.values = self._unpack_values(values)

    def _unpack_values(self,values):
        if not isinstance(values,MyTypes): 
            raise TypeError("Type not supported")
        else:
            if isinstance(values, list): 
                return "list"
            elif isinstance(values, Foo):
                return "Foo"
            elif isinstance(values, np.ndarray):
                return "np.ndarray"
            else:
                return ValueError("Something went wrong")

f = Foo(values=Foo(values=[1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify that the return type of a method is the same as the class itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel)

Comment: Thanks. Not using MyTypes and instead solved the problem. This explains why I never encountered this problem, because I just started playing around with annotationts. Thanks!

Comment: using `from __future__ import annotations` as recommended in the link does not solve the issue, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyTypes` only serve as the annotation to your `__init__`, since you can't have `Foo` reference before it's created, I'd recommend you forget about the annotation and just remove `MyTypes` altogether.

```
# MyTypes = (list,np.ndarray, Foo)
# I would remove this

class Foo:

    def __init__(self,values) -> None:
        self.values = self._unpack_values(values)

    def _unpack_values(self,values):
        # only start referencing Foo from here as a validation
        if not isinstance(values, (list, ndarray, Foo)): 
            raise TypeError("Type not supported")
        else:
            if isinstance(values, list): 
                return "list"
            elif isinstance(values, Foo):
                return "Foo"
            elif isinstance(values, np.ndarray):
                return "np.ndarray"
            else:
                return ValueError("Something went wrong")

f = Foo(values=Foo(values=[1,2,3]))
```

The challenge is that you can't reference Foo before `class Foo` or within its body until you're in the methods.  I don't see there's much benefit to have `MyTypes` so this would be the simplest fix.

Answer (score 0):

One ugly route you can go down is just make a shell class then add the methods from functions after the fact:

```
import numpy as np

class Foo():
    pass

MyTypes = (list,np.ndarray, Foo)

def __init__(self,values:MyTypes) -> None:
    self.values = self._unpack_values(values)

def _unpack_values(self,values):
    if not isinstance(values,MyTypes): 
        raise TypeError("Type not supported")
    else:
        if isinstance(values, list): 
            return "list"
        elif isinstance(values, Foo):
            return "Foo"
        elif isinstance(values, np.ndarray):
            return "np.ndarray"
        else:
            return ValueError("Something went wrong")

Foo.__init__ = __init__
Foo._unpack_values = _unpack_values

f = Foo(values=Foo(values=[1,2,3]))
```

[python tutor link to code](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20numpy%20as%20np%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20pass%0A%0AMyTypes%20%3D%20%28list,np.ndarray,%20Foo%29%0A%0Adef%20__init__%28self,values%3AMyTypes%29%20-%3E%20None%3A%0A%20%20%20%20self.values%20%3D%20self._unpack_values%28values%29%0A%0Adef%20_unpack_values%28self,values%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20not%20isinstance%28values,MyTypes%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20raise%20TypeError%28%22Type%20not%20supported%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20isinstance%28values,%20list%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22list%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elif%20isinstance%28values,%20Foo%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Foo%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elif%20isinstance%28values,%20np.ndarray%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22np.ndarray%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20ValueError%28%22Something%20went%20wrong%22%29%0A%0AFoo.__init__%20%3D%20__init__%0AFoo._unpack_values%20%3D%20_unpack_values%0A%0Af%20%3D%20Foo%28values%3DFoo%28values%3D%5B1,2,3%5D%29%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=1&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)