# What is the static type of self?

Tags: python, self, type-hinting

I want to constrain a method parameter to be of the same type as the class it's called on (see the end for an example). While trying to do that, I've come across this behaviour that I'm struggling to get my head around.

The following doesn't type check

```py
class A:
    def foo(self) -> None:
        pass

A.foo(1)
```

with

> error: Argument 1 to "foo" of "A" has incompatible type "int"; expected "A"

as I'd expect, since I'd have thought `A.foo` should only take an `A`. If however I add a self type

```py
from typing import TypeVar

Self = TypeVar("Self")

class A:
    def foo(self: Self) -> None:
        pass

A.foo(1)
```

it does type check. I would have expected it to fail, telling me I need to pass an `A` not an `int`. This suggests to me that the type checker usually infers the type `A` for `self`, and adding a `Self` type overrides that, I'm guessing to `object`. This fits with the error

```py
from typing import TypeVar

Self = TypeVar("Self")

class A:
    def bar(self) -> int:
        return 0

    def foo(self: Self) -> None:
        self.bar()
```

> error: "Self" has no attribute "bar"

which I can fix if I bound as `Self = TypeVar("Self", bound='A')`

Am I right that this means `self` is not constrained, in e.g. the same way I'd expect `this` to be constrained in Scala?

I guess this only has an impact if I specify the type of `self` to be anything but the class it's defined on, intentionally or otherwise. I'm also interested to know what the impact is of overriding `self` to be another type, and indeed whether it even makes sense with how Python resolves and calls methods.

**Context**

I want to do things like

```py
class A:
    def foo(self: Self, bar: List[Self]) -> Self:
        ...
```

but I was expecting `Self` to be constrained to be an `A`, and was surprised that it wasn't.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't seem to make any sense. There's absolutely no benefit to trying to change the type of `self`.What are you trying to accomplish by changing the type of `self`?

Comment: pretty sure its type is just the object itself, and no it wouldn't make sense

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't want to change the type of `self`. I want to use `Self` for other types in the method signature (not shown here)

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `@staticmethod`s here?

Comment: @Dan for brevity

Comment: _"I'm interested to know what the impact is of overriding self to be another type"_ - it will cause the class to behave unexpectedly.

Comment: IMHO static (or class) methods would be the Pythonic approach. If you're defining a ton of static methods (where brevity is a problem), you can avoid the duplication by using a class decorator or custom metaclass. There be dragons in overriding self.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

#### `self` is only half-magic.

The `self` arg has the magical property that, if you call an attribute of an object as a function, and that function has `self` as its first arg, then the object itself will be prepended to the explicit args as the `self`.

I guess any good static analyzer would take as implicit that `self` has the class in question as its type, which is what you're seeing in your first example.

#### `TypeVar` is for polymorphism.

And I think that's what you're trying to do? In your third example, `Self` can be any type, *depending on context*. In the context of `A.foo(1)`, `Self` is `int`, so `self.bar()` fails.

It may be possible to write an *instance method* that can be called *as a static method* against class non-members with parametric type restrictions, but it's probably not a good idea for any application in the wild. Just name the variable something else and declare the method to be static.

Comment: i seem to have given the wrong impression of what I'm trying to do. I don't want to do anything weird to the type of `self`. I'm surprised that (mypy in this case) is letting it be anything other than `type(self)`

Comment: So is all you're trying to do is use the class itself in the type-hint of the other args? I think v3.9 is supposed to support that seamlessly, and in the mean time I'm pretty sure you can do `def foo(self, x: "A"):...`, yeah?

Comment: sort of, but using `Self` is more specific. If I subclass `A` (which I'm expecting to), `Self` becomes the subclass. Re 3.9, what's changing there?

Comment: I was miss-remembering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533514/10135377) post, which is referring to the use of [future imports](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) and [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/). Note that there's some discussion in the sibling answers of exactly the stuff you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you omit a type hint on `self`, the type checker will automatically assume it has whatever the type of the containing class is.

This means that:

```
class A:
    def foo(self) -> None: pass
```

...is equivalent to doing:

```
class A:
    def foo(self: A) -> None: pass
```

If you want `self` to be something else, you should set a custom type hint.

---

Regarding this code snippet:

```
from typing import TypeVar

Self = TypeVar("Self")

class A:
    def foo(self: Self) -> None:
        pass

A.foo(1)
```

Using a TypeVar only once in a function signature is either malformed or redundant, depending on your perspective.

But this is kind of unrelated to the main thrust of your question. We can repair your code snippet by instead doing:

```
from typing import TypeVar

Self = TypeVar("Self")

class A:
    def foo(self: Self) -> Self:
        return self

A.foo(1)
```

...which exhibits the same behaviors you noticed.

But regardless of which of the two code snippets we look at, I believe the type checker will indeed assume `self` has the same type as whatever the upper bound of `Self` is while type checking the body of `foo`. In this case, the upper bound is `object`, as you suspected.

We get this behavior whether or not we're doing anything fancy with self or not. For example, we'd get the exact same behavior by just doing:

```
def foo(x: Self) -> Self:
    return x
```

...and so forth. From the perspective of the type checker, there's nothing special about the `self` parameter, except that we set a default type for it if it's missing a type hint instead of just using `Any`.

---

> error: "Self" has no attribute "bar"
>
> which I can fix if I bound as `Self = TypeVar("Self", bound='A')`
>
> Am I right that this means `self` is not constrained, in e.g. the same way I'd expect `this` to be constrained in Scala?

I'm unfamiliar with how `this` is constrained in Scala, but it is indeed the case that if you chose to override the default type of `self`, you are responsible for setting your own constraints and bounds as appropriate.

To put it another way, once a TypeVar is defined, its meaning won't be changed when you try using it in a function definition. This is the rule for TypeVars/functions in general. And since mostly there's nothing special about `self`, the same rule also applies there.

(Though type checkers such as mypy will also try doing some basic sanity checks on whatever constraints you end up picking to ensure you don't end up with a method that's impossible to call or whatever. For example, it complain if you tried setting the bound of `Self` to `int`.)

---

Note that doing things like:

```
from typing import TypeVar, List

Self = TypeVar('Self', bound='A')

class A:
    def foo(self: Self, bar: List[Self]) -> Self:
        ...

class B(A): pass

x = A().foo([A(), A()])
y = B().foo([B(), B()])

reveal_type(x)  # Revealed type is 'A'
reveal_type(y)  # Revealed type is 'B'
```

...is [explicitly supported by PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#annotating-instance-and-class-methods). The mypy docs also have [a few examples](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self).