# Type annotations for a class with attributes of the same type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, type-annotation

I have the Node class and the Node class has 2 children, child A and B, but they are the same class with the same structure, because the child could have its own child.

The code is in python, and the language don't let my do the next, mark me an error:

```py
class Node:
    a: Node
    b: Node
    name: str
    value: int
```

Is there a way to do that, the Object itself nested?

My regards

Comment: thanks @martineau, i removed the screenshot and wrote the code. look better, the post look better.

Answer (score 3):

According to [How do I specify that the return type of a method is the same as the class itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel), the simplest solution is to use a string with the class name:

```
a : 'Node'
```

Comment: Seems odd that you have answered a question that you voted to close.