# How to state, in Pydantic, that a staticmethod/classmethod returns an instance of the class in question?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, flake8, pydantic

I'm working in Python 3.7 and have something like this

```
class A(object):

  def __init__(self, value: int):
    self.value = value
  
  @classmethod
  def factory(cls, value: int) -> A:
    return A(value=value)
```

Yes, it's a contrived example, but I'm essentially trying to annotate the factory function to state that it returns an instance of `A`, however, this fails when I attempt to run the `flake8`  linter over the file as it complains that `A` isn't defined.

Is there some way to annotate this function such that the linter won't complain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid this by annotating with `'A'` instead:

```py
class A:
    @classmethod
    def factory(cls, value: int) -> 'A':
        ...
```

Alternatively you can use [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) [annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/):

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

and keep annotating with `A`.

Comment: not sure who downvoted you but you're correct, more information is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel

Comment: I downvoted because the answerer marked as a duplicate and then copied the answer from the duplicate to get free rep.

Comment: @AnthonySottile Nope, it was the other way round, I answered the question then I discovered the duplicate.

Comment: generally you should delete your answer then

Comment: @AnthonySottile Where did you get that information? [Other people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132600/397492) seem to think differently.

Comment: here's [newer advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266551/812183) -- but generally when there's nothing added by an answer or the question over the duplicate I'll self-delete and save the roomba some trouble

Comment: @AnthonySottile Well we have different opinions then. I think only bad or wrong content should be deleted. 10k+ rep users can view deleted content and the fact that an answer has been deleted carries some (mis)information: a user might think its content is wrong when it's not.