# Why is self not type hinted in Python

Tags: python, mypy

I've  been  looking into type hinting my code but noticed that Python programmers typically do not type hint `self` in their programs

Even when I look at the docs, they do not seem to type hint self, see
[here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types). This is from version 3.10 post forward declarations

```
    def __init__(self, value: T, name: str, logger: Logger) -> None:
```

I can understand why this is an issue before type annotations were introduced in 3.7 with Forward declarations

More info
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533514/1059273) and [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/)

---

The reason this seems useful to me is mypy seems able to catch bugs with this problem

example:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Simple(object):
    def __init__(self: Simple):
        print(self.x)
```

would return this from mypy

```
mypy test.py 
test.py:5: error: "Simple" has no attribute "x"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Which if you remove the type from `self` becomes

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

---

- Is there a reason that `self` is not annotated or is this only convention?
- Are there trade offs I'm missing or is my annotation of `self` wrong for some reason?

Comment: It's not needed -- the type of `self` is guaranteed to be the class.

Comment: How am I not myself?

Comment: Yeah I totally agree. Maybe the job is to make `mypy` able to check the `self` parameters without needing the type hint? I think I ran across a problem where I wanted to see what would happen and then noticed. "hey mypy is picking up bugs I didn't know about" why don't I do this everywhere/

Comment: @Barmar "guaranteed" -> "expected"

Comment: @khelwood Yeah, I regretted the choice of words immediately. But it's as "guaranteed" as any other type annotation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mypy usually handles the type of `self` without needing an explicit annotation. You're running into a different problem - a method with no argument or return type annotations is not type-checked at all. For a method with no non-`self` arguments, you can avoid this by annotating `self`, but you can also avoid it by annotating the return type.

Comment: [Relevant mypy settings](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html?highlight=check_untyped_defs#untyped-definitions-and-calls)

Comment: While both is possible, I think annotating the return type (using `-> None` if nothing is returned) instead of `self` is the more canonic solution in this case.