# Circular import despite absolute imports

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have got a problem with circular imports in Python 3.9.
I know there are numerous articles, questions and answers about this topic and I really have read a lot of them and about how to circumvent but I cannot figure out why it happens in my case. As far as I have understood one can circumvent circular imports by doing absolute imports:

This is my Stacktrace:

```
partially initialized module 'myproject.myapp.service.linepattern.corner' has no attribute 'Corner' (most likely due to a circular import)

  File "/mnt/d/User/Programming/MyProject/myproject/myapp/service/linepattern/line.py", line 8, in Line
    def __init__(self, cornerRight: cc.Corner, cornerLeft: cc.Corner) -> None:
  
  File "/mnt/d/User/Programming/MyProject/myproject/myapp/service/linepattern/line.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Line(ABC):
  
  File "/mnt/d/User/Programming/MyProject/myproject/myapp/service/linepattern/corner.py", line 2, in <module>
    import myproject.myapp.service.linepattern.line as cl
  
  File "/mnt/d/User/Programming/MyProject/myproject/myapp/service/linepattern/cornermanager.py", line 2, in <module>
    import myproject.myapp.service.linepattern.corner as cc
  
  File "/mnt/d/User/Programming/MyProject/myproject/tests/myapp/test_cornermanager.py", line 3, in <module>
    import myproject.myapp.service.linepattern.cornermanager as cm
```

and this is my file hierarchy

```
/mnt/d/User/Programming/MyProject
├── manage.py
├── myproject
│   ├── myapp
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── service
│   │   │   └── linepattern
│   │   │       ├── cornermanager.py
│   │   │       ├── corner.py
│   │   │       ├── line.py
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── myapp
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── test_cornermanager.py
```

and finally my code

cornermanager.py

```
import myproject.myapp.service.linepattern.corner as cc

class CornerManager:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.cornerList: List[cc.Corner]
        for i in range(1, 2):
            self.cornerList.append(cc.Corner(i, self))
        for corner in self.cornerList:
            corner.initializeLines()

    def corner(self, cornerNr: int) -> cc.Corner:
        return self.cornerList[cornerNr - 1]
```

corner.py

```
import myproject.myapp.service.linepattern.cornermanager as cm
import myproject.myapp.service.linepattern.line as cl

class Corner:
    def __init__(self, cornerNumber: int, cornerManager: cm.CornerManager) -> None:
        self.cornerNumber = cornerNumber
        self.cornerManager = cornerManager
        self.lineSet: Set[cl.Line]
        
    def initializeLines(self) -> None:
        #Add lines to the corner including its neighbor
        if self.cornerNumber == 1:
            self.lineSet.add(cl.Line(self, self.cornerManager.corner(2)))
        elif self.cornerNumber == 2:
            self.lineSet.add(cl.Line(self, self.cornerManager.corner(2)))

    
    def addLine(self, line: cl.Line) -> None:
        #Remove line from both corners
        for corner in cl.cornerPair():
            corner.lineSet.add(line)
        
    def removeLine(self, line: cl.Line) -> None:
        #Remove line from both corners
        for corner in cl.cornerPair():
            corner.lineSet.remove(line)
```

line.py

```
import myproject.myapp.service.linepattern.corner as cc

class Line:
    def __init__(self, cornerRight: cc.Corner, cornerLeft: cc.Corner) -> None:
        self.rightCorner = cornerRight
        self.leftCorner = cornerLeft        
    
    def cornerPair(self) -> Tuple[cc.Corner, cc.Corner]:
        #Return both corners
        return (self.rightCorner, self.leftCorner)
```

Comment: "As far as I have understood one can circumvent circular imports by doing absolute imports:" Sadly, no. Circular imports are a dependency problem between modules. *How* these modules are identified is inconsequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you put in the question (three separated modules), by including the following code at the top of each file should be able to fix the problems:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

In short this code will treat annotations as `strings`. You can read more about this at: [`Type hint of the enclosing class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class) and [`Evaluation of annotations`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/).

For the errors, this actually how Python executes your modules (start from `cornermanager.py`):

1. `import corner`. With this Python first saves the module in its internal module (`sys.modules`) before running the imported module code.
2. In `corner.py` itself, the first two lines are `import statement`, so let's start with `import cornermanager`. Again, Python saves the module in its internal module then executes the code in `cornermanager`.
3. Back to `cornermanager.py`. As we know first line of this module is `import corner`, but because Python already saved this module (`corner`) in its internal module, it doesn't import it the second time. That is, Python skips it and executes code below this line. Interestingly, because `corner` hasn't executed all its code but the first line (`import cornermanager`), attempt to fetch its `Corner class` will not succeed.