# How can pass "self" class to function in side class python

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-class

I got 2 instances interact with each other, describe in class like

```
class Fraction:

  def __init__(self, top, bottom):
    self.num = top
    self.den = bottom

  def add(self, B: Fraction):
    # do add two fractions
```

This causes `NameError: name 'Fraction' is not defined` in line `def add(self, B: Fraction):`. I want to catch their type before passing to function like `def add(self, B: int):` in Python 3.7 or newer

I know that just ignore the type of B or catch type error inside function but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class)

Comment: I would recommend something like `Union[Fraction, int, float]`, as it would make sense to allow something like `Fraction(3,4) + 1` to evaluate to `Fraction(7, 4)`.

Comment: Thanks. I have solved my problem