# Scope of return type hints in Python

Tags: python, scope, annotations, type-hinting

I have two classes, A and B, both of which have methods that return an instance of the other. This situation works just fine when I am not using type hinting, however, I am unable to incorporate type hinting, as in the following example:

```
class A:
    def return_B_with_out_annotation(self):
        return B()
    
    def return_B_with_annotation(self) -> B():
        return B()


class B:
    pass
```

Executing the above code (in Python 3.8) produces the following error:

```
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

So my question is, why is the method `A.return_B_with_out_annotation`  valid code, while `A.return_B_with_annotation` is not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python 3.7+

You need to add the following import to allow you to use type hints for classes not yet defined

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

[PEP 563 is where this behaviour is proposed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the method `return_B_with_annotation` in the A class is not yet aware of class B outside its scope.
There are two ways you can overcome this issue.
One is to create Class B first before A as shown below

```
class B:
    pass
class A:
    def return_B_with_out_annotation(self):
        return B()
    
    def return_B_with_annotation(self) -> B():
        return B()
```

Or else you should import annotations from the **future** module to the python
as

> from **future** import annotations

and your code will be

```
from __future__ import annotations

class A:
def return_B_with_out_annotation(self):
    return B()

def return_B_with_annotation(self) -> B():
    return B()


class B:
pass
```

^This one is more recommended.