# How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class and update that with inheritance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

Similar but different to [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class).

How can I set something on the parent class so that a type hint gets updated through inheritance?

```
class A:
    # Make some change here
    def foo(self, bar: 'A'):
        pass


class B(A):
    # Get the hinting of the code below, but without writing it for every inheritor.
    # def foo(self, bar: 'B'):
    #     pass
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TypeVar` to parameterise over the type of `self`. This is always an instance of "the current class", allowing to use the `TypeVar` to express the type respecting inheritance:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

Self = TypeVar('Self')

class A:
    # `bar` must be of the same type as `self`
    def foo(self: Self, bar: Self):
        ...


class B(A):
    ...
```

When calling `A().foo` or `B().foo`, `Self` is automatically inferred to the concrete class `A` or `B`, respectively. This then automatically constraints the other parameter to match the inferred `TypeVar` and thus the class.

---

The same mechanism can be used for `@classmethod`s as well. Instead of `self: Self` to capture the type of the instance, use `cls: Type[Self]` to capture the type directly.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type

Self = TypeVar('Self')

class A:
    # `bar` must be an instance of `cls`
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls: Type[Self], bar: Self):
        ...


class B(A):
    ...
```