# Static type checking in Python: What to use for self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am trying to use type checking in Python but am running into an issue on what type of parameter should be used when referring to `self`.

```
class MyClass:
  def my_func(self: TYPE?) -> str:
    return 'Hello world!'
```

What I am guessing is that it should be of type MyClass but I am not sure about this.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the type of `self` can't be know statically, as it depends on the MRO of the run-time type of `self`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class and update that with inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729161/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class-and-update-that)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the type in quotations to refer to it self (i.e. refer to the class via a string).

```
class MyClass:
    def my_func(self: 'MyClass') -> str:
        return 'Hello world!'
```

However, it's not necessary to use type annotation in this case as the `self` parameter is passed implicitly and is therefore known.