# Annotate return type for function returning nested class

Tags: python, python-typing

I have this python code:

```
class A:
        
    def foo(self) -> B:
        return A.B()
        
    class B:
        pass
```

The interpreter complains about my return type annotation that `name 'B' is not defined`. Obviously I can fix this by moving B to the top of class A.

First question: is there a way around this, so that I can keep `class B` at the bottom of the file?

Second question: why do I have to write `A.B()` in the return statement but `B` (without `A`) in the type annotation?

**Edit:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533514/8494588) answers part one of my question, but I'd be interested in an answer to the second part.

Comment: The second part is just how class scopes work. The ``def`` including defaults and annotations is evaluated in the scope of the class body – which has a ``B``. The function body is evaluated after the class body is consumed – there is no more ``B``, only ``A.B`` on the now-global ``A``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for your explanation. Makes sense, and it's actually what I thought could be the case. The possibility would have been some multl-phase name lookup as exists e.g. in C++.