# Typing with a type that references itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

How would I do typing for the following?

```
class Scope:
    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[Scope] = None) -> None:
        self.parent = Scope
```

`Scope` can receive a parent scope. In C I would do something like:

```
struct Env {
    struct Env parent;
    ...
};
```

Or provide a forward declaration. How would this be done in python's typing? Otherwise I just get a straight error:

> NameError: name 'Scope' is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class)

Comment: @SuperStormer yes it does :D