# python : can't create a function - that refer to X - inside a class X?

Tags: python

I want to create some static functions e.g. `isEqual`.
However, I can't create a function, that is in scope of class `X`, and also refer to `X`.   <--[1]

MCVE : https://ideone.com/mCjl3l

```
class X :
    str_myField = "" 
     # parameterized constructor 
    def __init__(self, str_myField ): 
        self.str_myField =str_myField 
    def isEqual(x1 : X,x2: X ):     #<==== name 'X' is not defined
        return x1.myField == x2.myField 
        
X_a = X();
X_a.str_myField ="a"

X_b = X();
X_b.str_myField ="b"
print(">>"+X.isEqual(X_a,X_b))
```

I got `name 'X' is not defined` error.

### Question

1. Is there such the limitation [1] in python?
   (It is true in C++, false in Java, but I am new to Python.)
2. I want to create many static utility functions for `X`.
   Is it a bad practice to create a new class `X_Util` (instead of `X`) to contain such functions instead?

I don't want to remove the explicit type (i.e. I love `x1:X` more than just `x`).

### Edit

After I got the great link ( [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class) )  suggested by Goion, I have tried to add `from __future__ import annotations` at the first line.

The solution is :-

```
from __future__ import annotations

class X :
    str_myField = "" 
     # parameterized constructor 
    def __init__(self ): 
        self.str_myField ="default"
    def isEqual(x1 : X,x2: X ):
        return x1.str_myField == x2.str_myField 
        
X_a = X();
X_a.str_myField ="a"

X_b = X();
X_b.str_myField ="b"
print(">>"+str(X.isEqual(X_a,X_b)))
```

Comment: instead of type hinting you can perform a check with `isinstance(x1, X)`

Comment: @Bill :: Thank a lot.  Does such change have some negative impact on auto-complete?

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm not sure i can answer that question. but i would add that to perform such functions like `.equals()` you might want to try dunder methods (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dunder-magic-methods-python/) like `__eq__()`, which would override the `==` operator.

Comment: Maybe this can help [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class)

Comment: Python uses `==` to check equality. The behavior can be overwriting by implementing `__eq__`. Your method violates a couple of other conventions as well: snake_case names, `self` as the first argument...

Comment: @Goion :: It is really useful.  Thank for the great link.

Comment: @Klaus D.  :: I never know that my code is that bad.  Thanks, I will study those aspects. ^^

Comment: @Carcigenicate :: at the very first glance, no  (  https://ideone.com/QVTvoB )  Perhaps, I need to read it more.

Comment: That's a separate error. You said that the constructor takes one argument, but you don't supply one when creating the object.

Comment: @Carcigenicate :: oh no, i am sorry. It works now.

Comment: @Carcigenicate :: I just did it.  Thank!