# Type hint for return value in subclass

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I am writing a CustomEnum class in which I want to add some helper methods, that would then be available by the classes subclassing my CustomEnum. One of the methods is to return a random enum value, and this is where I am stuck. The function works as expected, but on the type-hinting side, I cannot figure out a way of saying *"the return type is the same type of cls"*.

I am fairly sure there's some `TypeVar` or similar magic involved, but since I never had to use them I never took the time to figure them out.

```py
class CustomEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def random(cls) -> ???:
        return random.choice(list(cls))


class SubclassingEnum(CustomEnum):
    A = "a"
    B = "b"

random_subclassing_enum: SubclassingEnum
random_subclassing_enum = SubclassingEnum.random() # Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "CustomEnum", variable has type "SubclassingEnum")
```

Can somebody help me or give me a hint on how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting in Python 3.11, the correct return annotation for this code is `Self`:

```
from typing import Self
class CustomEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def random(cls) -> Self:
        return random.choice(list(cls))
```

Quoting from [the PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-classmethod-signatures):

> This PEP introduces a simple and intuitive way to annotate methods that return an instance of their class. This behaves the same as the TypeVar-based approach specified in PEP 484 but is more concise and easier to follow.
>
> The current workaround for this is unintuitive and error-prone:
>
> ```
> Self = TypeVar("Self", bound="Shape")
> class Shape:
>     @classmethod
>     def from_config(cls: type[Self], config: dict[str, float]) -> Self:
>         return cls(config["scale"])
> ```
>
> We propose using `Self` directly:
>
> ```
> from typing import Self
> class Shape:
>     @classmethod
>     def from_config(cls, config: dict[str, float]) -> Self:
>         return cls(config["scale"])
> ```
>
> This avoids the complicated `cls: type[Self]` annotation and the TypeVar declaration with a bound. Once again, the latter code behaves equivalently to the former code.

Comment: I am vary happy with this change (https://youtu.be/qw2TD91Nytg?t=43)

Answer (score 19):

The syntax here is kind of horrible, but I don't think there's a cleaner way to do this. The following [passes MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=2a0ee6bbbb786fdeb2ccf9d8dd6c0819):

```
from typing import TypeVar
from enum import Enum
import random 

T = TypeVar("T", bound="CustomEnum")

class CustomEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def random(cls: type[T]) -> T:
        return random.choice(list(cls))
```

(In python versions <= 3.8, you have to use `typing.Type` rather than the builtin `type` if you want to parameterise it.)

##### What's going on here?

`T` is defined at the top as being a type variable that is "[bound](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)" to the `CustomEnum` class. This means that a variable annotated with `T` can only be an instance of `CustomEnum` or an instance of a class inheriting from `CustomEnum`.

In the classmethod above, we're actually using this type-variable to define the type of the `cls` parameter with respect to the return type. Usually we do the opposite — we usually define a function's return types with respect to the types of that function's input parameters. So it's understandable if this feels a little mind-bending!

We're saying: this method leads to instances of a class — we don't know what the class will be, but we know it will either be `CustomEnum` or a class inheriting from `CustomEnum`. We also know that whatever class is returned, we can guarantee that the type of the `cls` parameter in the function will be "one level up" in the type heirarchy from the type of the return value.

In a lot of situations, we might know that `type[cls]` will always be a fixed value. In those situations, it would be possible to hardcode that into the type annotations. However, it's best *not* to do so, and instead to use this method, which clearly shows the relationship between the type of the input and the return type (even if it uses horrible syntax to do so!).

> *Further reading: the MyPy documentation on [the type of class objects](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects).*

##### Further explanation and examples

For the vast majority of classes (not with `Enum`s, they use metaclasses, but let's leave that aside for the moment), the following will hold true:

**Example 1**

```
Class A:
    pass

instance_of_a = A()
type(instance_of_a) == A # True
type(A) == type # True
```

**Example 2**

```
class B:
    pass

instance_of_b = B()
type(instance_of_b) == B # True
type(B) == type # True
```

For the `cls` parameter of your `CustomEnum.random()` method, we're annotating the equivalent of `A` rather than `instance_of_a` in my *Example 1* above.

- The type of `instance_of_a` is `A`.
- But the type of `A` is not `A` — `A` is a class, not an instance of a class.
- Classes are not instances of classes; they are either instances of `type` or instances of custom metaclasses that inherit from `type`.
- No metaclasses are being used here; ergo, the type of `A` is `type`.

The rule is as follows:

- The type of all python **class instances** will be the class they're an instance of.
- The type of all python **classes** will be either `type` or (if you're being too clever for your own good) a custom metaclass that inherits from `type`.

With your `CustomEnum` class, we *could* annotate the `cls` parameter with the metaclass that the `enum` module uses (`enum.EnumType`, [if you want to know](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/enum.py)). But, as I say — best not to. The solution I've suggested illustrates the relationship between the input type and the return type more clearly.

Comment: I see, I tried your approach on my own, but I didn't know about the bound option, and got a "Returning Any from function declared to return T" error message. Now I know what was wrong!

Comment: Glad I could help!