# How do I annotate a function whose return type depends on its argument?

Tags: python, api-design, type-hinting, python-typing, dependent-type

In Python, I often write functions that filter a collection to find instances of specific subtypes.  For example I might look for a specific kind of nodes in a DOM or a specific kind of events in a log:

```py
def find_pre(soup: TagSoup) -> List[tags.pre]:
    """Find all <pre> nodes in `tag_soup`."""
    …

def filter_errors(log: List[LogEvent]) -> List[LogError]:
    """Keep only errors from `log`.""" 
    …
```

Writing types for these functions is easy.  But what about generic versions of these functions that take an argument to specify which types to return?

```py
def find_tags(tag_soup: TagSoup, T: type) -> List[T]:
    """Find all nodes of type `T` in `tag_soup`."""
    …

def filter_errors(log: List[LogEvent], T: type) -> List[T]:
    """Keep only events of type `T` from `log`.""" 
    …
```

(The signatures above are wrong: I can't refer to `T` in the return type.)

This is a fairly common design: `docutils` has `node.traverse(T: type)`, `BeautifulSoup` has `soup.find_all()`, etc.  Of course it can get arbitrarily complex, but can Python type annotations handle simple cases like the above?

Here is a MWE to make it very concrete:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import *

@dataclass
class Packet: pass

@dataclass
class Done(Packet): pass

@dataclass
class Exn(Packet):
    exn: str
    loc: Tuple[int, int]

@dataclass
class Message(Packet):
    ref: int
    msg: str

Stream = Callable[[], Union[Packet, None]]

def stream_response(stream: Stream, types) -> Iterator[??]:
    while response := stream():
        if isinstance(response, Done): return
        if isinstance(response, types): yield response

def print_messages(stream: Stream):
    for m in stream_response(stream, Message):
        print(m.msg) # Error: Cannot access member "msg" for "Packet"

msgs = iter((Message(0, "hello"), Exn("Oops", (1, 42)), Done()))
print_messages(lambda: next(msgs))
```

Pyright says:

```
  29:17 - error: Cannot access member "msg" for type "Packet"
  Member "msg" is unknown (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

**In the example above, is there a way to annotate `stream_response` so that Python type checkers will accept the definition of `print_messages`?**

Comment: Does [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) of the typing documentation help at all? `TypeVar` seems like what you need.

Comment: @Kemp: it doesn't: in `def f(x: T) -> List[T]`,  the return type depends on the *type* of `x`.  In `def f(x: type) -> List[x]` (what I want/need), the return type depends on the *value* of `x`.

Comment: I'm confused. If you know that the `stream` parameter in `stream_response` is a function that will either return `None` or an instance of `Packet` (as per your type annotation for that parameter), then surely the return type of `stream_response` has to be `Iterator[Union[Packet, None]]`

Comment: @AlexWaygood: No, the return type is more precise: first, it's never `None`; and second, it's guaranteed to be a specific type of packet (whichever is passed in `types`.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. Can the elements of `types` (which I'm presuming to be a tuple of types) be guaranteed to be members of some pre-determined set of types known at compile time, or could they be `<any type that is a subtype of Packet>`?

Comment: @AlexWaygood The latter preferably, but the former would be OK as a last resort.

Comment: One more question (apologies!) — is there any limit to how long many members might be in the `types` tuple, or could it be of any length?

Comment: In practice, it won't be more than 10 in my case; I'm very curious to see what role that will play!

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher I rolled back your edit; `dependent-type` is an appropriate label here AFAICT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here we go. It passes MyPy --strict, but it isn't pretty.

##### What's going on here

For a given class `A`, we know that the type of an instance of `A` will be `A` (obviously). But what is the type of `A` itself? Technically, the type of `A` is `type`, as all python classes that don't use metaclassses are instances of `type`. However, annotating an argument with `type` doesn't tell the type-checker much. The syntax used for python type-checking to go "one step up" in the type hierarchy is, instead, `Type[A]`. So if we have a function `myfunc` that returns an instance of a class inputted as a parameter, we can fairly simply annotate that as follows:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')

def myfunc(some_class: Type[T]) -> T:
    # do some stuff
    return some_class()
```

Your case, however, is rather more complex. You could be inputting one class as a parameter, or you could be inputting two classes, or three classes... etc. We can solve this problem using `typing.overload`, which allows us to register multiple signatures for a given function. These signatures are ignored entirely at runtime; they are purely for the type-checker; as such, the bodies of these functions can be left empty. Generally, you only put a docstring or a literal ellipsis `...` in the body of functions decorated with `@overload`.

I don't think there's a way of generalising these overloaded functions, which is why the maximum number of elements that could be passed into the `types` parameter is important. You have to tediously enumerate every possible signature of your function. You may want to think about moving the `@overload` signatures to a separate .pyi stub file if you go down this route.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import (
    Callable,
    Tuple,
    Union,
    Iterator,
    overload,
    TypeVar,
    Type, 
    Sequence
)

@dataclass
class Packet: pass

P1 = TypeVar('P1', bound=Packet)
P2 = TypeVar('P2', bound=Packet)
P3 = TypeVar('P3', bound=Packet)
P4 = TypeVar('P4', bound=Packet)
P5 = TypeVar('P5', bound=Packet)
P6 = TypeVar('P6', bound=Packet)
P7 = TypeVar('P7', bound=Packet)
P8 = TypeVar('P8', bound=Packet)
P9 = TypeVar('P9', bound=Packet)
P10 = TypeVar('P10', bound=Packet)

@dataclass
class Done(Packet): pass

@dataclass
class Exn(Packet):
    exn: str
    loc: Tuple[int, int]

@dataclass
class Message(Packet):
    ref: int
    msg: str

Stream = Callable[[], Union[Packet, None]]

@overload
def stream_response(stream: Stream, types: Type[P1]) -> Iterator[P1]:
    """Signature if exactly one type is passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[Type[P1], Type[P2]]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2]]:
    """Signature if exactly two types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[Type[P1], Type[P2], Type[P3]]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3]]:
    """Signature if exactly three types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[Type[P1], Type[P2], Type[P3], Type[P4]]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4]]:
    """Signature if exactly four types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[Type[P1], Type[P2], Type[P3], Type[P4], Type[P5]]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5]]:
    """Signature if exactly five types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[Type[P1], Type[P2], Type[P3], Type[P4], Type[P5], Type[P6]]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6]]:
    """Signature if exactly six types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""

@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[
        Type[P1], 
        Type[P2],
        Type[P3],
        Type[P4], 
        Type[P5],
        Type[P6],
        Type[P7]
    ]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7]]:
    """Signature if exactly seven types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[
        Type[P1], 
        Type[P2],
        Type[P3],
        Type[P4], 
        Type[P5],
        Type[P6],
        Type[P7],
        Type[P8]
    ]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8]]:
    """Signature if exactly eight types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[
        Type[P1], 
        Type[P2],
        Type[P3],
        Type[P4], 
        Type[P5],
        Type[P6],
        Type[P7],
        Type[P8],
        Type[P9]
    ]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9]]:
    """Signature if exactly nine types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[
        Type[P1], 
        Type[P2],
        Type[P3],
        Type[P4], 
        Type[P5],
        Type[P6],
        Type[P7],
        Type[P8],
        Type[P9],
        Type[P10]
    ]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P10]]:
    """Signature if exactly ten types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""

# We have to be more generic in our type-hinting for the concrete implementation 
# Otherwise, MyPy struggles to figure out that it's a valid argument to `isinstance`
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream,
    types: Union[type, Tuple[type, ...]]
) -> Iterator[Packet]:
    
    while response := stream():
        if isinstance(response, Done): return
        if isinstance(response, types): yield response

def print_messages(stream: Stream) -> None:
    for m in stream_response(stream, Message):
        print(m.msg)

msgs = iter((Message(0, "hello"), Exn("Oops", (1, 42)), Done()))
print_messages(lambda: next(msgs))
```

---

##### Strategies for making this less verbose

If you wanted to make this more concise, one way of achieving that is to introduce an alias for certain typing constructs. The danger here is that the intent and meaning of the type hint gets quite difficult to read, but it does make overloads 7-10 look a lot less horrific:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import (
    Callable,
    Tuple,
    Union,
    Iterator,
    overload,
    TypeVar,
    Type, 
    Sequence
)

@dataclass
class Packet: pass

P1 = TypeVar('P1', bound=Packet)
P2 = TypeVar('P2', bound=Packet)
P3 = TypeVar('P3', bound=Packet)
P4 = TypeVar('P4', bound=Packet)
P5 = TypeVar('P5', bound=Packet)
P6 = TypeVar('P6', bound=Packet)
P7 = TypeVar('P7', bound=Packet)
P8 = TypeVar('P8', bound=Packet)
P9 = TypeVar('P9', bound=Packet)
P10 = TypeVar('P10', bound=Packet)

_P = TypeVar('_P', bound=Packet)
S = Type[_P]

T7 = Tuple[S[P1], S[P2], S[P3], S[P4], S[P5], S[P6], S[P7]]
T8 = Tuple[S[P1], S[P2], S[P3], S[P4], S[P5], S[P6], S[P7], S[P8]]
T9 = Tuple[S[P1], S[P2], S[P3], S[P4], S[P5], S[P6], S[P7], S[P8], S[P9]]
T10 = Tuple[S[P1], S[P2], S[P3], S[P4], S[P5], S[P6], S[P7], S[P8], S[P9], S[P10]]

@dataclass
class Done(Packet): pass

@dataclass
class Exn(Packet):
    exn: str
    loc: Tuple[int, int]

@dataclass
class Message(Packet):
    ref: int
    msg: str

Stream = Callable[[], Union[Packet, None]]

@overload
def stream_response(stream: Stream, types: Type[P1]) -> Iterator[P1]:
    """Signature if exactly one type is passed in for the `types` parameter"""

@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[Type[P1], Type[P2]]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2]]:
    """Signature if exactly two types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[Type[P1], Type[P2], Type[P3]]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3]]:
    """Signature if exactly three types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[Type[P1], Type[P2], Type[P3], Type[P4]]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4]]:
    """Signature if exactly four types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[Type[P1], Type[P2], Type[P3], Type[P4], Type[P5]]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5]]:
    """Signature if exactly five types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: Tuple[Type[P1], Type[P2], Type[P3], Type[P4], Type[P5], Type[P6]]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6]]:
    """Signature if exactly six types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""

@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: T7[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7]]:
    """Signature if exactly seven types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: T8[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8]]:
    """Signature if exactly eight types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: T9[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9]]:
    """Signature if exactly nine types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""
    
@overload
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream, 
    types: T10[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P10]
) -> Iterator[Union[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P10]]:
    """Signature if exactly ten types are passed in for the `types` parameter"""

# We have to be more generic in our type-hinting for the concrete implementation 
# Otherwise, MyPy struggles to figure out that it's a valid argument to `isinstance`
def stream_response(
    stream: Stream,
    types: Union[type, Tuple[type, ...]]
) -> Iterator[Packet]:
    
    while response := stream():
        if isinstance(response, Done): return
        if isinstance(response, types): yield response

def print_messages(stream: Stream) -> None:
    for m in stream_response(stream, Message):
        print(m.msg)

msgs = iter((Message(0, "hello"), Exn("Oops", (1, 42)), Done()))
print_messages(lambda: next(msgs))
```

Comment: Ah, the the trick of using a bound on the type parameter is quite clever.  The tuple overloads are unpleasant, but the one-type case at least is pretty decent!

Comment: @Clément, agreed -- the one-type case is a common pattern when annotating `classmethod`s that return an instance of the class https://stackoverflow.com/a/68283181/13990016

Comment: Excellent catch, and great answer there too! +1

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: @Clément -- I thought of a way you could make this a *little* bit less verbose; have edited it into my answer. It does make the annotation even less readable, however!

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly what I was looking for, but did not dare to do this way