# Python return type hint of subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a class method in Base class:

```
class Base：
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls): -> ????
         return [a list of cls()]

class Sub(Base):
    ...
```

How should I define ???? to receive hint when calling `Sub.foo()[0]` in Pycharm? I tried `List[Type[Base]]` but it only shows attributes of Base class

Thanks

Comment: Should it not be `List[Base]`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282879/type-hint-for-return-value-in-subclass

Comment: You'll want to look into Generics and Type Variables. See the duplicate linked above.

Comment: Thank you guys, will definitely check those links