# Inheritable custom class constructor in python

Tags: python, inheritance, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

How can I implement a custom constructor (class method) that is inheritable in python?

The following minimized example might give an idea:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


@dataclass
class Parent:
    something: int = 2

    @classmethod
    def from_float(cls: Type[T], something_as_float: float) -> T:
        return Type[T](something=int(something_as_float))


@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    """ Should also be constructible via from_float
    """


assert isinstance(Parent.from_float(1.0), Parent)
assert isinstance(Child.from_float(1.0), Child)
```

mypy does not like the constructor I call when returning from from_float. I don't know how to refer to class (Parent or Child) from the class method.

Comment: You mean like an instance factory?

Comment: not sure... adding a C++ pattern so that I can implement a Rust pattern in python feels like I would just be adding fuel to the garbage fire though :)

Comment: Why don't you  implement the `__new__` method ?

Comment: The @dataclass implicitly adds the constructor (and __new__too?) that takes the fields, and I can't disturb that. I'm trying to add rust inspired conversion methods onto some existing dataclasses that inherit from each other, and I can't change the dataclasses-with-inheritance part of the design.

Comment: `Type[T]` is not the constructor; `cls` is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [type hint for return value in subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282879/type-hint-for-return-value-in-subclass)

Comment: " I don't know how to refer to class (Parent or Child) from the class method." *with `cls* of course*. That's the *whole point* of a `classmethod`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `bound` argument to `TypeVar` to specify that the type is a subclass of `Parent`. This lets mypy know that the type has the `something` attribute

When you create the instance use `cls` not `Type[T]`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound='Parent')


@dataclass
class Parent:
    something: int = 2

    @classmethod
    def from_float(cls: Type[T], something_as_float: float) -> T:
        return cls(something=int(something_as_float))


@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    pass


assert isinstance(Parent.from_float(1.0), Parent)
assert isinstance(Child.from_float(1.0), Child)
```

Comment: Whoooo that did it. Thanks! I can confirm locally that it runs with out asserting, and also passes mypy!

Comment: You can't refer a class within its definition... and escaping as cls: "Parent" and -> "Parent" didn't help either. I hit "The erased type of self "minimized_typing_puzzle.Parent" is not a supertype of its class "Type[minimized_typing_puzzle.Parent]"" and then error: "Parent" not callable. Iain's solution works, but feel free to keep the thread going if you enjoy typing puzzles. Thanks!