# Is overriding __new__ in a child class to create particular parent class instances an antipattern?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'd like to override `__new__` in a child class to force it to create instances of the parent class, providing defaults for some of the keyword arguments of the parent.

It's designed to just be some nice sugar when creating parent class instances.

- Is this a terrible idea? If so, what's the right way to do this?
- Is it a known pattern?
- How will my favourite type checker be able to cope?

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, profession: str):
        self.name = name
        self.profession = profession

class Teacher(Person):
    def __new__(self, name: str):
        return Person(name=name, profession="teacher")

rita = Person("Rita", profession="surgeon")
bob = Teacher("Bob")  # type checkers think `bob` is a Teacher.
```

Comment: Why not just write a normal factory function? `def teacher(name): return Person(name=name, profession='teacher')`?

Comment: Or maybe `def __init__(self, name: str): super().__init__(name, "teacher")`?

Comment: Indeed: why not use standard inheritance patterns?

Comment: the `__new__` should "create parent class" or instance?

Comment: What's the point of even having a `class Teacher` if no instances of that class can ever exist?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica With my dodgy method, it's obvious that I'm creating a class instance when I do `Teacher("Bob")`, but `teacher("Bob")` doesn't look like a class instance. Maybe if I called it `create_teacher("Bob")`?

Comment: @cards Oops. I'll fix the question.

Comment: I don't see anything *particularly* wrong with this, but I'm not sure I understand why you're defining `__new__` in the subclass rather than overriding `__init__`. In class `Teacher`, you could have `def __init__(self, name): super().__init__(name=name, profession='teacher')`

Comment: @AlexWaygood for complicated reasons later on, I want to create an instance of `Person`, not of `Teacher`. This is really just a sugary helper to create `Person(profession="Teacher", **kwargs)`

Comment: For all intents and purposes, a `Teacher` *is* a `Person` as per inheritance. If that's a problem later on, then *that's* the real code smell and this workaround is just a symptom of it…

Comment: `Person(profession="Teacher", **kwargs)` seems much better, as in simpler and clearer, than this somewhat convoluted approach. To quote the zen of Python: "Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex."

Comment: @LondonRob — in that case I'd say this is a bit of an antipattern then,  yes. You have a construct that claims to create a new class at first glance, but in fact doesn't. Why not write a classmethod alternative constructor in your `Person` class?. `def make_teacher(cls, name): return cls(name=name, profession='teacher')`

Comment: @AlexWaygood "You have a construct that claims to create a new class at first glance, but in fact doesn't." yes, I think this is a very persuasive argument _against_ doing this. It's surprising that you don't endup with a `Teacher` instance.

Answer (score 4):

As [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69441858/is-overriding-new-in-a-child-class-to-create-particular-parent-class-instanc?noredirect=1#comment122751236_69441858) rightly points out, a user would be surprised to request a `Teacher` but not get one:

```py
>>> bob = Teacher("Bob")
>>> isinstance(bob, Teacher)
False  # ???
```

This is a good argument against this pattern.

A more typical approach might involve some helper methods on the parent class to assist with creation:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, profession: str):
        self.name = name
        self.profession = profession

    @classmethod
    def create_teacher(cls, name: str) -> Person:
        return cls(name=name, profession="teacher")
```

This means users of your code can create teachers without having to remember the magic string "teacher". Instead they can use autocomplete:

[image: Autcomplete with create_teacher as a suggestion]

Perhaps the OO-wizards on StackOverflow can come up with an even more appealing method than this, but this satisfies my requirements, and my type checker is happy that `bob` is indeed a `Person`.

Comment: "This means users of your code can create teachers without having to remember the magic string "teacher"." - but that brings up another issue. Why do you have a magic string? Why is `"teacher"` special, and if it's special, why don't you have a constant somewhere for it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion that's a slight tweak on @LondonRob's answer: if possible, use an `Enum` instead of magic strings to specify a `Person`'s profession.

```
from enum import Enum, auto
from typing import TypeVar

class Profession(Enum):
    TEACHER = auto()
    SURGEON = auto()

P = TypeVar('P')

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, profession: Profession) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.profession = profession

    @classmethod
    def create_teacher(cls: type[P], name: str) -> P:
        return cls(name=name, profession=Profession.TEACHER)
```

This has the advantage that you can test the person's profession much more cleanly:

```
>>> Bob = Person.create_teacher('Bob')
>>> Bob.profession is Profession.TEACHER
True
```

In fact, you could even generalise your alternative constructor by making it an *instance* method of your `Profession` class,  rather than a classmethod on your `Person` class:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from enum import Enum, auto

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, profession: Profession) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.profession = profession

class Profession(Enum):
    TEACHER = auto()
    SURGEON = auto()

    def create(self, name: str) -> Person:
        return Person(name=name, profession=self)
```

In usage:

```
>>> Bob = Profession.TEACHER.create(name='Bob')
>>> Suzie = Profession.SURGEON.create(name='Suzie')
```

As an aside, if your class is essentially a wrapper around structured data, then you could also consider using `dataclasses` (whether or not you go the `Enum` route):

```
from enum import Enum, auto
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar

class Profession(Enum):
    TEACHER = auto()
    SURGEON = auto()

P = TypeVar('P')

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    profession: Profession

    @classmethod
    def create_teacher(cls: type[P], name: str) -> P:
        return cls(name=name, profession=Profession.TEACHER)
```

Comment: Oooh fancy. I like it. I've always been a bit mystified by `TypeVar('P')` stuff. Do type checkers know that `bob` is a `Person` with this `-> P` business?

Comment: @LondonRob yes, they do! And by using a `TypeVar`, you ensure that the type hint for your `classmethod` constructor won't break if you ever decide to make a "proper" subclass of `Person` :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282879/type-hint-for-return-value-in-subclass