# What is the pylance subscript error trying to tell me about my dictionary?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

I have the following piece of code:

```
for table in list(my_dict.keys()):
    if table in my_other_dict:
        for file in my_dict[table]:
            if file in my_other_dict[table]:
                my_dict[table].remove(file)
                if not my_dict[table]:
                    del my_dict[table]
```

But the second, third and fourth `my_dict` reference is underlined with the following error:

> Subscript for class "dict" will generate runtime exception; enclose
> type annotation in quotes

The only more or less relevant internet source I can find about it is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class), but I do not understand how I can apply it to my case.

Indeed, when this little piece of code is executed, there is no runtime exception.

Moreover, the last `my_dict` reference is underlined with the following error message:

> Generic class type cannot be deleted

This dictionary is built and returned by the following function (signature only, content is too big):

```
def meta_from_iso_to_utf(self, correct_meta_files):
```

How do I fix my code so that pylance stops complaining about these problems which do not seem to be problems as the code runs as expected ?

---

Edit 1 (to answer Frank's comment):

`my_dict` is defined like this:

```
some_dict, my_dict = object.meta_from_iso_to_utf(
    argument
)
```

In the method, the `my_dict` is defined like so in a loop:

```
my_dict[key].append[value[0]]
```

`table` is the variable containing the keys of `my_dict` during the loop, which is a string. This variable is used only in this loop.

Concerning my editor, it is `visual studio code 1.60.1`, with the Python extension from microsoft version `v2021.9.1246542782`

Comment: How is `my_dict` defined?  Which IDE are you using?  Are first glance, this code seems perfectly fine.  It almost seems like it thinks that table is a type rather than a variable.   Is there any code near you that uses `table` as a type?

Comment: Which version of pylance are you using?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1145

Comment: I don't get these warning using the same setup and pylance v2021.9.2. Is it possible to create a [mre]? I found some possible relevant information, but it does not apply to the code you currently have in your question. The root cause may be in the part you left out though.

Comment: @wovano.  I agree.  It feels like the poster is including some library that defines `table` to be a class.  That's what I'm guessing based on the error messages.  Obviously the code is fine.

Answer (score -2):

Today I got this kind of error if I add a type annotation like this one:

```
errors: list[str]
```

This leads to "Subscript for class "list" will generate runtime exception; enclose type annotation in quotes".

So to your question "What is the pylance subscript error trying to tell me".
It means that if you use `list` in this context as type annotation and not as actual list declaration then you should put it in double quotes to avoid errors. So if I change my code to:

```
errors: "list[str]"
```

pylance is happy. As to your specific code sample I can only imagine that it happens there because pylance for some reason detects that this must be part of a type annotation and not the actual usage of the dict type.