# Complete Class Python

Tags: python, class

I am doing an assignment and it is not going very well. It is my code which is not working super good:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Node:
    value: int = None
    nxt: Node = None  

@dataclass
class Deque:
    head: Node = None      # First node in queue
    tail: Node = None      # Last node in queue
    size: int = 0

    def add_first(self, n):
        new = Node(n, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new
            self.tail = new
        self.size += 1


        s = "{ "
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            s += str(node.value) + " "
            node = node.nxt
        s += "}"
        return s

    
    def add_last(self, n):
        new = Node(n, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new
            self.tail = new
        else:
            self.tail.nxt = new
            self.tail = new
        self.size += 1

    def get_last(self):
        if self.tail is None:
            print("Get can't be applied on an empty list")
            return None
        else:
            return self.tail.value       

    def get_first(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("Get can't be applied on an empty list")
            return None
        else:
            #node = self.head
            return self.head.value

    def remove_first(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("Remove can't be applied on an empty list")
        elif self.head == self.tail:
            s = self.head.value
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None
            self.size -= 1
            return s
        elif self.size == 1:
            node = self.head
            self.head = self.head.nxt
            self.size -= 1
            return node.value
```

Output:
{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
Size: 10
{ 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
Size: 20

Update:
I found an answer to my question. It was issues regarding def add_first and def remove last as well as def remove first.

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me is that your `remove_first()` and `remove_last()` methods only handle the cases of the deque being empty, or only containing one item.  They completely ignore the usual case of two or more items.

Comment: FYI you can refer to a class within its own definition by using a string, like `'Node'`, rather than with `Any`. See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references and https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533514/6273251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is homework I'm not going to give away the fixed code, but I will point out what needs fixing. I believe I figured out all the required fixes, but I could be wrong since you didn't share the code used to test your Deque:

1. Your `add_first` method is unnecessarily stepping through all the
   Nodes, then setting the last Node (the `tail`)'s `nxt` value to the
   new Node, meaning the new Node will appear at the end of the Deque.
   Instead, all you need to do is set the `nxt` of the new Node to the
   current `head`, and set `head` to the new Node.
2. Your `remove_first` doesn't account for any case except if there's
   one Node in the Deque. You have to set the Deque's `head` to its old
   `head`'s `nxt` Node in all other cases.
3. Your `remove_last` also doesn't account for any case except if
   there's one Node in the Deque. In all other cases, you have to loop
   through the Deque's Nodes, starting with `head`, until you find a
   Node whose `nxt` value is the Deque's `tail`, then set its `nxt` to
   None, and set the Deque's `tail` to that Node.
   Example of finding the Node before the `tail` Node:

   ```
   node = self.head
   while node.nxt != self.tail:
       node = node.nxt
   node.nxt = None
   self.tail = node
   ```

Comment: I changed add_first:
`def add_first(self, n):`
        `new = Node(n, None)`
        `if self.head is None:`
            `self.head = new`
            `self.tail = new`
        `else:`
            `new.nxt = self.head`
            `self.head = new`
        `self.size += 1`

Comment: @user17020522 it's hard to read code in a comment, better to put it at the end of your question, but regardless, that code's logic looks identical to the version I wrote, so it looks good to me.

Comment: Okay, i did a few updates but still do not understand regarding loop in both removes. 1 minute. i change my post

Comment: "you have to loop through the Deque's Nodes, starting with head, until you find a Node whose nxt value is the Deque's tail, then set its nxt to None, and set the Deque's tail to that node."
`remove_last`
while self.head is not None:
    if node.nxt == self.tail:
        node == None

Comment: @user17020522 I'll add some example code for that.

Comment: i found an answer

Comment: thank you for your kindness