# Can I use experimental types from typing_extensions?

Tags: python, python-typing

To be more specific:

To solve questions like [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33533148/383793)
[PEP 673](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/) introduces `typing.Self`. The PEP is a Draft, but it currently an experimental type in typing_extensions 4.0.0

I tried using this in python 3.8

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class MenuItem:
    url: str
    title: str
    description: str = ""
    items: typing.List[typing_extensions.Self] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)
```

But it raises

```
TypeError: Plain typing_extensions.Self is not valid as type argument
```

I could just use the literal string "MenuItem" instead. But I was wondering why this doesn't work.

Comment: This looks like a bug in `typing_extensions`, TBH. The metatype of ``Self`` is usually used for "non types" such as ``Union``, ``Literal`` or ``NoReturn``; its only actual type ``Any`` is special cased by ``typing``.

Comment: "It will be in Python 3.11" — not necessarily! The PEP hasn't even been formally submitted to the Steering Council for consideration yet, let alone approved! You can see its status is still given as "draft": https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/. (To be clear, I support the PEP, and hope it is accepted.)

Comment: @AlexWaygood I must have read past that.

Comment: The PEP is now accepted, but I'm still getting the same error. `typing-extensions==4.3.0`, `mypy==0.971`, `python3.10.5`.

Comment: `pyright` correctly recognizes `Self` as a type, so the issue is probably in mypy.

Comment: As of today, `Self` is not implemented in mypy yet. Currently it's being worked on in this [PR](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/13133).

Comment: This commit was merged on 2022-11-15:  [`77dd4b4d`](https://github.com/python/mypy/commit/77dd4b4df5b8bcd716352144feeb78862427f4dd) but as of today, is not part of any tagged release of mypy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but be aware of the uses of the package:

> The `typing_extensions` module serves two related purposes:
>
> - Enable use of new type system features on older Python versions. For example,   `typing.TypeGuard` is new in Python 3.10, but
>   `typing_extensions` allows   users on previous Python versions to use
>   it too.
> - Enable experimentation with new type system PEPs before they are accepted and   added to the `typing` module.

This specific case was a [bug in typing_extensions](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/964). It's being [planned to get fixed in 4.0.1](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/968).

Comment: I have version 4.3.0 and am still getting the error. — edit: my error message is actually `Variable "typing_extensions.Self" is not valid as a type` which points to it being an issue in mypy, not (anymore) in typing_extensions. The pull request to fix this is still open as of the time of writing: https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/11666

Comment: @theberzi Yeah, that was also [mentioned in the comments on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083371/can-i-use-experimental-types-from-typing-extensions/70152211?noredirect=1#comment129392100_70083371)