# Type hint for class method return error - name is not defined?

Tags: python, pylint, python-typing

The following class has a class method `create()`, which as a type hint for return type, for creating an instance of the class.

```
class X:
   @classmethod
   def create(cls) -> X:
     pass
```

However, it got the following error?

> NameError: name 'X' is not defined

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class

Comment: Wait, that link says PEP563 got pushed back. Why?! What on earth was it breaking that was so horrible? I'm tired of putting `__future__` imports in every file I write.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name `X` doesn't exist until the class is fully defined. You can fix this by importing a `__future__` feature called `annotations`. Just put this at the top of your file.

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

This wraps all annotations in quotation marks, to suppress errors like this. It's the same as doing this

```
class X:
  @classmethod
  def create(cls) -> 'X': # <-- Note the quotes
    pass
```

but automatically. This will be the default behavior in some future Python version (originally, it was going to be 3.10, but it's been pushed back due to compatibility issues), but for now the import will make it behave the way you want.

The future import was added in Python 3.7. If you're on an older version of Python, you'll have to manually wrap the types in strings, as I did in the example above.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6. Do I need to add `from __future__ import annotations`  and add quotes to the type? (both of them)

Comment: Ah, the future import was added in 3.7. In that case, you'll need to explicitly wrap the type in quotes as I did in my second example, unfortunately.