# Name a nested typing.NamedTuple in the same outer class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inner-classes, type-hinting, namedtuple

I have a problem in Python I can work around, but I'd really like to understand why it doesn't work the way I think it should.

I have a class `A` which has nested `typing.NamedTuple`s B and C. So far so good. The problem arises when the nested named tuple `C` is supposed to have an attribute of type `A.B`, i.e. be of the type of the first named tuple, like so:

```
import typing

class A:
  class B(typing.NamedTuple):
    foo: int

  class C(typing.NamedTuple):
    bar: B
```

So using `B` does not work with the following error message `NameError: name 'B' is not defined`, although following working code suggests it should:

```
import typing

class A:
  class B(typing.NamedTuple):
    foo: int

  foobar = B(3)
```

(This code also checks out using mypy, btw)

So I tried:

```
  class C(typing.NamedTuple):
    bar: A.B
```

which checks out in mypy but fails when run with `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`

So my question is can I even have an attribute of class C be typed to A.B? If so, how do I do that?

Thanks!

PS: The stuff works of course without type hints using classes/collections.NamedTuple, etc.

Comment: Executing your code gives the error `NameError: name 'typing' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, I was missing one space on the import statement and it did not make into the code block. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to : [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533514/11384184)

Here you have a slight variant where the type of your `C.bar` is of a nested class of the parent of C, but it still ends the same way : Python gets lost.

You can add double-quotes to your type-hint (`bar: "B"`) so that it will not cause a NameError. It would have to be `bar: "A.B"` for mypy to pass.
Or you can add **at the very top of your file** `from __future__ import annotations`.