# Can I pass an instance of a class to one of its own methods in Python?

Tags: python, oop, importerror, python-typing

For my terminal Uno game, I want to have a very simple `Card` class that has two attributes: colour and value.
In this class, I also want to have a method that takes another card as an argument, and checks whether putting the initial card on this `topCard` would be a legal move.
The code as written down below works perfectly fine with my other files, but I feel like it could benefit from some better type annotation.

```py
import typing

class Card:
    def __init__(self, colour: str, value: typing.Union[str, int]):
        self.colour = colour
        self.value = value # can be string or int (e.g., 'Reverse' or 6)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'[{self.colour} | {self.value}]'

    def is_valid_move(self, topCard) -> bool:
        if self.colour == 'Black': # always legal
            return True
        elif self.colour == topCard.colour or self.value == topCard.value:
            return True
        return False
```

Because I want to be as strict as possible (as far as Python allows any strictness of course), I want `is_valid_move` to look like this:

```py
def is_valid_move(self, topCard: Card) -> bool:
    ...
```

By default my IDE shows the yellow squiggly line under `Card`, and when running the code I get  `NameError: name 'Card' is not defined`.

When I try to `from card import Card` — the file is called card — I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Card' from partially initialized module 'card' (most likely due to a circular import)`.
This does seem to fix the squiggly line issue and according to my IDE nothing is wrong, but if it doesn't run I assume that this can not be the way to handle things.

So my question is: Is there any way to use `Card` as a type hint for one of it's own methods?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @sudden_appearance It does, thank you! Should I close this issue or is it not exactly a duplicate question?