# How to sync type-hinting between vscode and mypy

Tags: visual-studio-code, mypy, pylance

For example the following (silly) example will raise an error within vscode:

```py
class Something:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def something_else(self, y) -> Something:
        return Something(self.x + y)
```

Seen here:

[image]

Where as `mypy script.py` will return no errors.

I'm not sure what the difference is here, but I'd rather mypy took priority as that's what I'm using to catch type errors.

Answer (score 1):

`Something` isn't defined as it won't be defined until the class definition is complete. You'll notice that running this code will cause a `NameError`, so in this case Pylance and Pylint are correct and you  probably shouldn't silence their warnings.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class) for how to fix that.

Comment: Ah I was using 3.10 so I thought `__future__ annotations` wasn't needed, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately they pushed that feature back since it broke too many things.