# How come staticmethod return type hints can't include the class itself?

Tags: python, static-methods, type-hinting

Consider this example:

```
class MyObj(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_list_of_instances() -> list[MyObj]:
        my_instances = []
        # some code that populates my_instances with instances of MyObj
        return my_instances
```

Using Python 3.9.10 I get the following exception

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'MyObj' is not defined
  File "example.py", line 3, in MyObj
    def get_list_of_instances() -> list[MyObj]:
  File "example.py", line 1, in <module>
    class MyObj(object):
```

How come the static method return type hint can't include the class itself?

I can imagine this is a quirk of the interpreter, where the class isn't defined yet at this point. If so, is there an elegant workaround?

Comment: Depending on your version of python, there are workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class

Comment: The type hint is evaluated when the method is being defined, which is before the class name has been assigned.