# How to refine python type hints for methods returning a class instance when the class is inherited?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, mypy

I have a parent class with a method that returns an instance of that class.
This class has one (or several) children classes.

How to provide type hints to indicate that the method call on any child class will return an instance of that very child class and not the parent class?

For example, with the following code:

```py
from random import randint

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def get_random_person(cls) -> "Person":
        return cls("Random Guy", randint(18, 65))


class Player(Person):
    pass

def welcome_player(player: Player):
    print(f"Welcome {player.name}")


player = Player.get_random_person()
welcome_player(player)
```

The linter `mypy` would raise an error:

```py
error: Argument 1 to "welcome_player" has incompatible type "Person"; expected "Player"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Of course, you could do something like the following, but that is very heavy if the parent class is inherited multiple times:

```py
from random import randint
from typing import cast


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def get_random_person(cls) -> "Person":
        return cls("Random Guy", randint(18, 65))


class Player(Person):
    @classmethod
    def get_random_person(cls) -> "Player":
        return cast(Player, super().get_random_person())


def welcome_player(player: Player):
    print(f"Welcome {player.name}")


player = Player.get_random_person()
welcome_player(player)
```

Any suggestion on a smart way to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class)

Comment: Yes, it does. I searched for a long time on StackOverflow but could not find these related questions. It seems my searching skills are not that good ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`typing.TypeVar` with parameter `bound`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#annotating-instance-and-class-methods) to simulate:

```
from random import randint
from typing import TypeVar, Type


Self = TypeVar('Self', bound='Person')


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def get_random_person(cls: Type[Self]) -> Self:
        return cls("Random Guy", randint(18, 65))


class Player(Person):
    pass


def welcome_player(player: Player):
    print(f"Welcome {player.name}")


player: Player = Player.get_random_person()
welcome_player(player)
```

Python 3.11 will add the [`Self`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-673-self-type) type, but it has not been officially released yet. This is accessible in older versions with the `typing-extensions`, although `mypy` will complain that `error: Variable "typing_extensions.Self" is not valid as a type`).

```py
from random import randint
from typing_extensions import Self


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def get_random_person(cls) -> Self:
        return cls("Random Guy", randint(18, 65))


class Player(Person):
    pass

def welcome_player(player: Player):
    print(f"Welcome {player.name}")


player = Player.get_random_person()
welcome_player(player)
```