# In Python, is there a way to specify the type of a class-level field as being the object of the class?

Tags: python, class

Sorry if the question is a bit confusing but I didn't know how to phrase it better.

This is what I would like to do.

```
class Land():
    upgrades_available = 10
    market_type: str = ""
    land_list: list[Land] = []

def __init__(self, position: str, price: int):
    self.position: str = position
    self.price: int = price
    self.upgrade_level: int = 0
    Land.land_list.append(self)
```

Unfortunately the interpreter doesn't like the following line:

```
land_list: list[Land] = []   # Unresolved reference 'Land'
```

I can understand why that's not possible because I imagine an infinite loop could be the result, but is there a way around this? I would like the interpreter to recognize that this list contains Land objects for ducktyping.

Comment: `land_list: list["Land"] = []`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class)

Comment: I'm using 3.9. land_list: list["Land"] = [] works for me, thank you!