# When using a class method as a factory method, how do we do type hinting for the output?

Tags: python

In Python,

```
class Example:
  @classmethod
  def build_class_instance(cls, fixed_inputs:List[str],unchanged_args):List[str]:
      new_vars = f(fixed_inputs)
      return Example(new_vars,unchanged_args)
```

The problem now seems that for the output,  if I write `-> Example`, my IDE complains about it...

What should I write?

Comment: please mention which IDE you are using and correct the code in your question please. `def foo(cls, bar: int) -> str:` this works totally fine it's an `@classmethod`.

Comment: What's the complaint? If it's just that `Example` is not defined, you can use `'Example'` (a forward reference) instead, or use `from __future__ import annotations` so that *no* type hint is evaluated at runtime. Python 3.11 will introduce `Self` as a type hint; see [PEP-673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) for details.

Comment: Canonical dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33533148/3001761

Answer (score 0):

When the interpreter gets to the type annotation, the `Example` class is not yet fully defined. You can use a forward reference by putting the class name in quotes like this:

```py
class Example:
    @classmethod
    def build_class_instance(cls) -> 'Example':
        return Example()
```

**EDIT:**

As @ShadowRanger pointed out, you can also make use of this early on in your module:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

That way, you don't even need the quotes.

Comment: You should explain *why* this fixes the problem.

Comment: Also, the better way to solve this is to just add `from __future__ import annotations` to the top of the file (it makes all annotations implicitly treated the way explicitly quoting them to make them plain strings does). Eventually that deferred annotation evaluation will become the default behavior anyway, so may as well opt-in to the future now.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Fair enough.