# Method parameter type refering to the class it's defined in is causing AttributeError partially initialized module

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a dataclass in `extensions` > `__init__.py` like:

```py
@dataclass
class Range:
    start: date
    end: date

    def overlap(self, other: Range) -> bool:
      # method body removed
```

My IDE is complaining about the method parameter

```
Unresolved reference 'Range'
```

If I change the parameter type to

```py
def overlap(self, other: extensions.Range) -> bool:
```

IDE stops complaining but when I run my program I get

```
partially initialized module 'extensions' has no attribute 'Range' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I'm learning Typing in python and cannot figure out how to define this type in my method

Comment: Or if you're on Python 3.11 or greater, you can use [`typing.Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class#:%7E:text=Forward%20references,-When%20a%20type%20hint%20contains). You can use a forward reference in the form of a string.

```
@dataclass
class Range:
    start: date
    end: date

    def overlap(self, other: 'Range') -> bool:
        pass
```

Comment: Please don't answer the question, if you have already found a duplicate. Just flag the question as duplicate. If you have something to add to existing answers, post your answer on the duplicate target.