# Can a linked list class in python take a 'next' value in the constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For convenience, I'd like to use a linked list `Node` class like the following:

```
a = Node(3)
b = Node(2, a)
c = Node(1, b) # c = (1) -> (2) -> (3)
```

I've tried the following class definition

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val: int, next_node: Node = None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next_node
```

... but I'm getting a `NameError` about `Node` in the constructor.

I recognize that this is recursive, but nevertheless I've seen this done in other languages. Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `typing.Self` to refer to the `Node` type.

```py
from typing import Self
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val: int, next_node: Self = None):
```

Alternatively, use the string `'Node'`.

Comment: Tried that but now getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'Self' from 'typing'`. I've confirmed I have no circular dependencies, any idea?

Comment: @MaxDarling Your Python version might be too low. In that case, just use the string `'Node'` as the type hint.

Comment: replacing that with `from __future__ import annotations` compiles. taken from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class). not sure why that works...

Comment: I'm on 3.10.9 :C

Comment: @MaxDarling That works because it'll delay the evaluation of annotations, at which point `Node` is defined. It is essentially the same as using a string to annotate the type (e.g. `'Node'`).