# Is there a way to "dynamically" annotate the return type of a function in Python?

Tags: python, generics, mypy, python-typing, typing

Imagine I have the following class structure with three class families: `Parent`, `Child1`, and `Child2` each with `Abstract`, `Explicit` and `Implicit` flavors.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import abc

###################################
# Parent classes
###################################
class AbstractParent(abc.ABC):

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def type_explicit(self) -> type[AbstractExplicitParent]:
        pass

class AbstractExplicitParent(AbstractParent):
    pass

class AbstractImplicitParent(AbstractParent):
    pass

###################################
# Child 1 classes
###################################

class AbstractChild1(AbstractParent):

    @property
    def type_explicit(self) -> type[ExplicitChild1]:
        return ExplicitChild1

class ExplicitChild1(AbstractExplicitParent, AbstractChild1):
    pass

class ImplicitChild1(AbstractImplicitParent, AbstractChild1):
    pass

###################################
# Child 2 classes
###################################

class AbstractChild2(AbstractParent):

    @property
    def type_explicit(self) -> type[ExplicitChild2]:
        return ExplicitChild2

class ExplicitChild2(AbstractExplicitParent, AbstractChild2):
    pass

class ImplicitChild2(AbstractImplicitParent, AbstractChild1):
    pass
```

The details of these classes aren't important except for the fact that I've defined an abstract property called `type_explicit` in `AbstractParent` with concrete implementations in `AbstractChild1` and `AbstractChild2`. The obvious purpose of this property is to return the explicit flavor of the current class, and you can see that `AbstractChild1.type_explicit` returns `ExplicitChild1` and similarly for `AbstractChild2.type_explicit`.

Now imagine I want to define a function that can accept any subclass of `AbstractParent` but always returns the explicit flavor of that subclass. Obviously I can write

```
def some_function(a: AbstractParent) -> AbstractExplicitParent:
    ...
```

but that doesn't capture all the type information, for example: `(ImplicitChild1,) -> ExplicitChild1`.

Is there a way to dynamically compute the return type, say by defining a (meta)class called `Explicit` that can evaluate the `type_explicit` property, such that I can write

```py
T = TypeVar("T", bound=AbstractParent)
def some_function(a: T) -> Explicit[T]:
    ...
```

even if I need to change how `type_explicit` works, say by changing it to a class variable/method?

The only reason I think this could work is because of things like `typing.Type` which are sort of dynamic since I can write things like

```
def get_type(a: T) -> Type[T]:
    return type(a)
```

Comment: Sounds like yet another job for the missing [intersection](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) type to me because your "explicit" child classes are essentially intersections of the particular abstract child class and `AbstractExplicitParent`. The return annotation would be something like `Intersection[T, AbstractExplicitParent]`. Shame it isn't possible yet.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg, thanks for pointing that out, an intersection would indeed be perfect for this application. Do you know what the best way to show my support for implementing this feature?

Comment: Judging by the state of this issue thread I would say there is not much you can say there that has not already been said. You can always just "thumb up" the OP and some remarks made by others that are relevant to you. I think it is not unlikely that implementation is under way. But who knows when it will be done. We are still waiting for the PEP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class