# Python typing: class method return its subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing, typing

I have the following situation: a parent class `Format` and some child classes, for example `FormatA` and `FormatB`:

```py
import abc

class Format(abc.ABC):

    def to_formatA(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def to_formatB(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    ...


class FormatA(Format):
   
    def to_formatA(self):
        return self
    
    def to_formatB(self):
        return FormatB()


class FormatB(Format):
    def to_formatA(self):
        return FormatA()
    
    def to_formatB(self):
        return self
```

What is the best way to apply typing annotations?

My Attempt:

```py
import abc
from typing import TypeVar

TFormat = TypeVar("TFormat", bound="Format")
TFormatA = TypeVar("TFormatA", bound="FormatA")
TFormatB = TypeVar("TFormatB", bound="FormatB")


class Format(abc.ABC):

    def to_formatA(self) -> TFormatA:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def to_formatB(self) -> TFormatB:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class FormatA(Format):

    def to_formatA(self) -> TFormatA:
        return self

    def to_formatB(self) -> TFormatB:
        return FormatB()


class FormatB(Format):

    def to_formatA(self) -> TFormatA:
        return FormatA()

    def to_formatB(self) -> TFormatB:
        return self
```

MyPy gives me different errors:

1. for each class, `to_formatA` and `to_formatB` methods give:

```
error: A function returning TypeVar should receive at least one argument containing the same TypeVar
```

Type Hint for `self`?

2. for row 21 and 33, respectively:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "FormatA", expected "TFormatA")
error: Incompatible return value type (got "FormatB", expected "TFormatB")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a string with the class name as a forward declaration.

```py
import abc

class Format(abc.ABC):

    def to_formatA(self) -> "FormatA":
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def to_formatB(self) -> "FormatB":
        raise NotImplementedError()
    ...


class FormatA(Format):
   
    def to_formatA(self) -> "FormatA":
        return self
    
    def to_formatB(self) -> "FormatB":
        return FormatB()


class FormatB(Format):
    def to_formatA(self) -> "FormatA":
        return FormatA()
    
    def to_formatB(self) -> "FormatB":
        return self
```

```bash
$ mypy a.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Alternatively, you can use `from __future__ import annotations` and use the annotations as-is. They'll be ignored by Python, but processed correctly by mypy:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import abc

class Format(abc.ABC):

    def to_formatA(self) -> FormatA:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def to_formatB(self) -> FormatB:
        raise NotImplementedError()
    ...


class FormatA(Format):
   
    def to_formatA(self) -> FormatA:
        return self
    
    def to_formatB(self) -> FormatB:
        return FormatB()


class FormatB(Format):
    def to_formatA(self) -> FormatA:
        return FormatA()
    
    def to_formatB(self) -> FormatB:
        return self
```

```bash
$ mypy a.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Thank you @BoppreH. 
However, I thought it was not generally the best choice to use strings and forward declaration. Am I Wrong? 
There is no way to handle the above situation with `TypeVar` and more in general without *forward declaration*?

Comment: @Papemax89 I don't think it's frowned upon. It's certainly simpler, and mypy doesn't seem to care either way. For more info, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class).

Comment: This seems entirely reasonable. But since it is generally a good idea to make return type annotations as _narrow_ as possible, I would suggest using [`typing.Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) to annotate `FormatA.to_formatA` and `FormatB.to_formatB`. This is will implicitly further constrain the return type, in case either for those classes is subclassed again. (For Python `<3.11` you can import it from `typing_extensions`.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't add a comment as I don't have enough reputation, but simply adding `from __future__ import annotations` should work:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import abc


class Format(abc.ABC):

    def to_formatA(self) -> FormatA:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def to_formatB(self) -> FormatB:
        raise NotImplementedError()
    ...


class FormatA(Format):
   
    def to_formatA(self) -> FormatA:
        return self
    
    def to_formatB(self) -> FormatB:
        return FormatB()


class FormatB(Format):
    def to_formatA(self) -> FormatA:
        return FormatA()
    
    def to_formatB(self) -> FormatB:
        return self
```

It remedies errors for me in VSCode, I am not familiar with MyPy however.

Comment: Thanks @Nater0214 for your response. However your proposal doesn't resolve mypy errors.

Comment: FYI, this *is* an answer, so you don't need to apologize for posting it as such instead of as a comment. (It's too often assumed that comments are appropriate for "trivial" answers.)

Comment: (I won't claim I never do it, but I *strive* to post a comment-answer only when using it to clarify a close-as-duplicate or close-as-typo vote.)