# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, nonetype, typing

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    """Class for keeping track of an item in inventory."""
    name: str | None = None
    unit_price: float
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'NoneType'

Python 3.9

I think the problem is using the latest version of python, how to solve it.

i tried use 'or'
but it didn't help

Answer (score 25):

`str | None` syntax is only supported in 3.10 or later. Use

```py
from typing import Optional
name: Optional[str] = None
```

For cases where the right hand side isn't `None` or there are more than two types, you can use `Union`

```py
from typing import Union
foo: Union[str, int, float] = "bar"
```

Comment: `Optional` is a nice type, and is a widely known type across multiple languages, +1 for that
However, an accurate equivalent to `|` in Python <= 3.9 would be `Union[type1, type2]` in a more general case

Comment: @PoneyUHC, good point, I've added an example for that case as well. Worth noting that `Optional[T]` is an alias for `Union[T, None]` in the `typing` module, not its own type.

Comment: This bug bit me today in deployment to production, but specifically in situations like: `class A: def test(self)->"A" | None: pass` . Looks like even in python3.11 this is still a problem. For now peeps should look at answers to [SO: How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class)