How to create a buffer around a line with manim?
I'm very new to manim! As such I hope my question is not inappropriate.
I have a line mobject and I would like to create a shape of specific size around, a so called 'buffer'. In the image you see a blue line, and the shape around it is what I like to create.
Is there some method which creates this sort of shape for line objects?
I really did try to find something by myself, but maybe I just don't use the correct wording in my search.
Is there some method in the library which does this?
I'm very sorry if my question is too broad or just in other ways not appropriate. I just started to learn manim!


UPDATE
I tried to accomplish this task by setting the stroke_width to a very high level. However, the ends are not round but sharp.
This is the code for it:
class CreateLineWithBuffer(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        street=Line(color=PINK).rotate(angle=45)
        street.scale(8)
        line = Line(stroke_width=50, stroke_opacity=0.5).rotate(angle=45)
        line.scale(8)
        
        self.play(Create(street), run_time=3)
        self.play(Create(line), run_time=3)
        self.wait()




I admittedly don't know manim all that well, but this effect can often be achieved by drawing the line with a fat pen.  You might check that.

That is an idea! I will check it out. Thank you!

You can draw a fat line using the Line parameter stroke_width, but you won't get these round edges at the end of the line. I was unable to find a parameter which would fulfill this task. I think the best way would be to write your own VMObject or even Line object.

Hi CodingWithMagga Thank you for providing me with more details on how to accomplish the fat line! I updated the code and the description of my question accordingly.
And yes, I think I may need to create an own object. I thought at somehow create some circle around the start and end point, and then connect the circles with some tangent?

Here is a possible solution. Note that the code can definitely be optimized/refactored, and I didn't test it that much (so bugs are included ;) ). But you can use that as a starting point.
from manim import *
import math
import numpy as np
from manim.typing import Point3D


def interpolate(
    start: int | float | Point3D, end: int | float | Point3D, alpha: float | Point3D
) -> float | Point3D:
    return (1 - alpha) * start + alpha * end


class BigLine(VMobject):
    def __init__(
        self,
        start: Point3D = LEFT,
        end: Point3D = RIGHT,
        buff: float = 0.2,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.buff = buff
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def generate_points(self) -> None:
        points = []
        start_point_pos_normal = self.start + self.buff * self.calc_normal(
            self.start, self.end
        )
        start_point_neg_normal = self.start - self.buff * self.calc_normal(
            self.start, self.end
        )
        end_point_pos_normal = self.end + self.buff * self.calc_normal(
            self.start, self.end
        )
        end_point_neg_normal = self.end - self.buff * self.calc_normal(
            self.start, self.end
        )

        first_arc = ArcBetweenPoints(
            end_point_pos_normal, end_point_neg_normal, angle=-TAU / 2
        )
        second_arc = ArcBetweenPoints(
            start_point_neg_normal, start_point_pos_normal, angle=-TAU / 2
        )

        nppcc = self.n_points_per_cubic_curve
        points.extend(
            interpolate(start_point_pos_normal, end_point_pos_normal, a)
            for a in np.linspace(0, 1, nppcc)
        )
        points.extend(first_arc.points)
        points.extend(
            interpolate(end_point_neg_normal, start_point_neg_normal, a)
            for a in np.linspace(0, 1, nppcc)
        )
        points.extend(second_arc.points)
        points.append(start_point_pos_normal)
        self.set_points(points)

    def calc_normal(self, first, second) -> Point3D:
        dx = second[0] - first[0]
        dy = second[1] - first[1]
        normal_vec = np.array([-dy, dx, 0])
        return normal_vec/np.linalg.norm(normal_vec)


class LineWidth(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        line = Line(2 * UL, 2 * DR, stroke_width=3)
        big_line = BigLine(2 * UL, 2 * DR, buff=1, fill_color=RED, fill_opacity=0.3)

        self.add(line, big_line)

        self.wait(3)



Wow, this is just awesome! Many thanks @CodingWithMagga!!
It needed some debugging, as I got the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type' for the type definitions. So I fixed it with 'Union' (to import that module: from typing import Union), e.g. start: int | float | Point3D to Union [int,float,Point3D]. Now it works like a charm. Thank you so much!

I hope it is okay, that I post the answer with the fixed code. Unfortunately it did not fit in the comment section, but I think for newbies like me it is always best to have a working script which you can copy-paste to try it out.

@i.i.k. Sure that's fine. Strange that it works like that in my case, maybe a different manim/python version or whatever. Anyway, great that it works now, happy coding :).

Regarding the TypeError: I found the information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76712720/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-type-and-nonetype

Many thanks to @CodingWithMaga!
The code needed fixing the errorTypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'.
To fix it I needed to adjust the type definitions with the help of the Union method from the typing lib.
This is the code of @CodingWithMaga but with the fixed TypeError:
from manim import *
import math
import numpy as np
from manim.typing import Point3D
from typing import Union

def interpolate(
    start: Union[int,float,Point3D], end: Union[int,float,Point3D], alpha: Union[float, Point3D] 
) -> Union [float, Point3D]:
    return (1 - alpha) * start + alpha * end


class BigLine(VMobject):
    def __init__(
        self,
        start: Point3D = LEFT,
        end: Point3D = RIGHT,
        buff: float = 0.2,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.buff = buff
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def generate_points(self) -> None:
        points = []
        start_point_pos_normal = self.start + self.buff * self.calc_normal(
            self.start, self.end
        )
        start_point_neg_normal = self.start - self.buff * self.calc_normal(
            self.start, self.end
        )
        end_point_pos_normal = self.end + self.buff * self.calc_normal(
            self.start, self.end
        )
        end_point_neg_normal = self.end - self.buff * self.calc_normal(
            self.start, self.end
        )

        first_arc = ArcBetweenPoints(
            end_point_pos_normal, end_point_neg_normal, angle=-TAU / 2
        )
        second_arc = ArcBetweenPoints(
            start_point_neg_normal, start_point_pos_normal, angle=-TAU / 2
        )

        nppcc = self.n_points_per_cubic_curve
        points.extend(
            interpolate(start_point_pos_normal, end_point_pos_normal, a)
            for a in np.linspace(0, 1, nppcc)
        )
        points.extend(first_arc.points)
        points.extend(
            interpolate(end_point_neg_normal, start_point_neg_normal, a)
            for a in np.linspace(0, 1, nppcc)
        )
        points.extend(second_arc.points)
        points.append(start_point_pos_normal)
        self.set_points(points)

    def calc_normal(self, first, second) -> Point3D:
        dx = second[0] - first[0]
        dy = second[1] - first[1]
        normal_vec = np.array([-dy, dx, 0])
        return normal_vec/np.linalg.norm(normal_vec)


class LineWidth(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        line = Line(2 * UL, 2 * DR, stroke_width=3)
        big_line = BigLine(2 * UL, 2 * DR, buff=1, fill_color=RED, fill_opacity=0.3)

        self.add(line, big_line)

        self.wait(3)

        self.play(Create(big_line), run_time=3)




